# Printing integers with thousands separators in Windows using C

Tags: c, windows, number-formatting

The question is pretty self-explanatory, I suppose. I am using printf and friends (snprintf etc) to display some memory statistics that are in the millions or hundreds-of-thousands range. Reading a number formatted like "1,523,556" is much easier than "1523556" to my lazy way of thinking.

I have tried setting the locale and using the apostrophe flag before the format specifier (%'d and %'llu), but the apostrophe is apparently a standard from the SUS, so it may not work for me under Windows anyway.

Is there a Windows-specific API for doing this? I am working with Pelles C and programming in straight ANSI C99.

** EDIT **

After reading the answers and the MSDN pages associated with them, I understand why .NET is the preferred method for Windows programming now. It smooths over a tremendous amount of API work.

Comment: This isn't really answer-worthy, but from the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/stdio/commaprint.html. I can not find any sort of Windows API that does this for you, and you aren't running a POSIX system that supports those `printf` modifiers.

Comment: @birryee Thanks for the comment. I had actually found this same page on the C FAQ, which reminded be about the apostrophe from programming under Linux. :-) No such luck on Windows though.

Comment: More related answers can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449805/how-to-format-a-number-from-1123456789-to-1-123-456-789-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Win32 API does provide a function that will format a number with thousands grouping (or whatever grouping is appropriate for the specified locale): `GetNumberFormat()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318110.aspx).

Unfortunately, it's a pretty painful API to use - not nearly as simple as the apostrophe format specifier in SUS (on the other hand, you get a lot of flexibility in exchange for the complexity)

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for but couldn't seem to find, thanks. And really most of the regular C Windows API's are painful to use. But powerful, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetNumberFormatEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318113%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (for Windows Vista and later).  The option `LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT` uses the preferences set in the Control Panel under regional and language options, including a thousands seperator.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is a correct and direct answer to my question, but my work computers (only a year old...) still all have XP on them. Pfft. I wish I could accept more than 1 answer.