# How to set comma as ytics separator on gnuplot

Tags: formatting, gnuplot

> NOTE: I have read the "set decimalsign lcale" in the manual - which
>   seems the usual advice.

However, that deals with changing the the usual English decimal point, not adding a thousands separator.

I would like to display my ytics as "2,000,000"

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See [gnuplot: How to enable thousand separators (digit grouping)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22328334/2604213).

Answer (score 0):

gnuplot uses the standard C-style formatting for its tic labels, so there isn't really a good way to do this automatically. If you know where you want the tics you can specify them manually, e.g.:

```
set ytics ("0" 0, "1,000,000" 1e6, "2,000,000" 2e6)
```

You can type `? set xtics` for more info.

If you want to do it automatically, there may be a way to write a gnuplot function implementing something like the solution [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/623905-printf-comma-formatting-question), but that may be more trouble than it is worth.