# Small space in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Does something like tiny space exist in gnuplot? I searching for something similar to, for instance, , in LaTeX.

```
set xlabel "2\,400\,000"
```

Comment: Not that I currently know of. If you absolutely need it, can't you use a LaTeX terminal, e.g. cairolatex or tikz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is an awkward workaround without using a LaTeX terminal, but using enhanced text (check `help enhanced`).

I assume you want a thousand separator. If you are working under Linux, the following might be of interest: [gnuplot: How to enable thousand separators (digit grouping)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22328334/7295599)

**Script:**

```
### small space between numbers
reset session

set termoption font "Arial,18"

set label 1 at graph 0.1,0.9 "2400000"
set label 2 at graph 0.1,0.8 "~2{.0}~ {.0 }40~0{.0}~ {.0 }000"
set label 3 at graph 0.1,0.7 "2 400 000"

plot x
### end of script
```

**Result:** (from wxt terminal under Windows)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unicode provides two options roughly equivalent to LaTeX \thinspace

```
U+2009   THIN SPACE              UTF-8: 0xE2 0x80 0x89
U+202F   NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE   UTF-8: 0xE2 0x80 0xAF
```

and another that may or may not be slightly smaller than that

```
U+2008  PUNCTUATION SPACE       UTF-8: 0xE2 0x80 0x88
```

You could copy-paste the utf-8 sequence directly into gnuplot but obviously it will be hard to see whether it worked or not :-)
It is probably better to provide the unicode value as an escape sequence.
Of course this only works if you are using a font that supports the unicode code point being used; otherwise it will probably substitute a normal space. It might also be sensitive to quirks in the various graphics libraries; for example I had better luck using the wxt terminal than I did with nominally the same font using the qt terminal.

```
set term wxt font "Arial,15"
set label 1 at graph 0.1,0.9 "2400000"
set label 2 at graph 0.1,0.8 "2{\U+2009}400{\U+2009}000"
set label 3 at graph 0.1,0.7 "2 400 000"
set label 4 at graph 0.1,0.6 "2{\U+202F}400{\U+202F}000"

plot x
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. That's certainly the better solution than my cumbersome approach ;-)