# Format a Large Number

Tags: c, numbers, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a number from 1123456789 to 1,123,456,789 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449805/how-to-format-a-number-from-1123456789-to-1-123-456-789-in-c)

How can I format a large integral number with commas in C, such that the readability is improved?

222222 should be 222,222 and 44444444 should be 44,444,444.

Comment: smartest? What does that even mean in this context?

Comment: For example the French will use a space as thousands separator and a comma as a decimal separator. A dot has no meaning.

Comment: I want it at 1000th intervals from the right end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do the formatting yourself; `printf` in Unix has a `'` modifier:

```
printf("%'d\n", number);
```

It looks like Visual Studio doesn't support that.  This syntax is locale-aware, however.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for Linux only, I tried there and it didn't work. I also found this: For some numeric conversions a radix character (`decimal point') or thousands' grouping character is used. The actual character used depends on the LC_NUMERIC part of the locale. The POSIX locale uses `.' as radix character, and does not have a grouping character. Thus,   printf("%'.2f", 1234567.89); - results in `1234567.89' in the POSIX locale, in `1234567,89' in the nl_NL locale, and in `1.234.567,89' in the da_DK locale. But how do I find out what is my locale? what is a locale?

Comment: @hari: What was your locale setting (usually, the `LANG` environment variable)?  Is it set to something other than `C`?

Comment: Jeremiah: I don't see anything. LANG is not set.

Comment: @hari: Look in your environment for the variables `LANG` and `LC_NUMERIC` and see what they are set to.  Try setting them to one of the examples you just pasted in (mine is `en_US.UTF-8`).

Comment: @hari: If your locale is not set, you get the POSIX locale you mention in your comment, which doesn't have thousands separators.  Try one of the other values and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: Jeremiah: I have 2 boxes: linux and freebsd. On linux : LANG=en_US.utf8 and LC_NUMERIC is not set. And on freeBSD both are undefined. BTW, its not working on linux also.

Comment: Jeremiah: thanks for the knowledge. I guess, I would not rely on locale and create my own function. Thanks much.

Comment: @hari: You must execute `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");` at program startup to acquire the locale settings for numerics (or you can use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` to acquire all locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulus (`%`) operation and build your own string.

Answer (score 1):

If you google for "c format thousands separator" then one of the hits is this page http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-402370.html
It's C++ though but it should give you an idea of what you can do.