# How can I format currency with commas in C?

Tags: c, ubuntu, printf, gnu, format-specifiers

I'm looking to format a Long Float as currency in C.  I would like to place a dollar sign at the beginning, commas iterating every third digit before decimal, and a dot immediately before decimal.  So far, I have been printing numbers like so:

```
printf("You are owed $%.2Lf!\n", money);
```

which returns something like

```
You are owed $123456789.00!
```

Numbers **should** look like this

```
$123,456,789.00
$1,234.56
$123.45
```

Any answers need not be in actual code.  You don't have to spoon feed.  If there are C-related specifics which would be of help, please mention.  Else pseudo-code is fine.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449805/how-to-format-a-number-from-1123456789-to-1-123-456-789-in-c

Comment: thanks for this as well.  It vash helpful.

Comment: I know this is somewhat out of the scope of your question, but you might not find a common way of doing this because storing currency values as floats is generally not a good idea.

Comment: because of a possible precision error?

Comment: +1 @airza.  beProactive - yes, fractions don't play well in base 2/base 10 conversions.  You're a lot better off just storing values in cents as integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `printf` might already be able to do that by itself with the `'` flag.  You probably need to set your locale, though.  Here's an example from my machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");
    printf("$%'.2Lf\n", 123456789.00L);
    printf("$%'.2Lf\n", 1234.56L);
    printf("$%'.2Lf\n", 123.45L);
    return 0;
}
```

And running it:

```
> make example
clang -Wall -Wextra -Werror    example.c   -o example
> ./example 
$123,456,789.00
$1,234.56
$123.45
```

This program works the way you want it to both on my Mac (10.6.8) and on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 10.10) I just tried.

Comment: this checks out on my ubuntu box.  Thanks mayne.

Comment: This is required by POSIX — [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a way-old post, but I disappeared down the `man` rabbit hole today, so I thought I'd document my travels:

There's a function called `strfmon()` that you can include with `monetary.h` that will do this, and do it according to local or international standards.

Note that it works like `printf()`, and will take as many `double` arguments as there are `%` formats specified in the string.

There's a lot more to it than what I have here, and I found this page to be the most helpful: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Numbers.html

```
#include <monetary.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    // need to setlocal(), "" sets locale to the system locale
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    double money_amt = 1234.5678;

    int buf_len = 16;
    char simple_local[buf_len];
    char international[buf_len];
    char parenthesis_for_neg[buf_len];
    char specified_width[buf_len];
    char fill_6_stars[buf_len];
    char fill_9_stars[buf_len];
    char suppress_thousands[buf_len];

    strfmon(simple_local, buf_len-1, "%n", money_amt);
    strfmon(international, buf_len-1, "%i", money_amt);
    strfmon(parenthesis_for_neg, buf_len-1, "%(n", money_amt);
    strfmon(specified_width, buf_len-1, "%#6n", money_amt);
    strfmon(fill_6_stars, buf_len-1, "%=*#6n", money_amt);
    strfmon(fill_9_stars, buf_len-1, "%=*#8n", money_amt);
    strfmon(suppress_thousands, buf_len-1, "%^=*#8n", money_amt);

    printf( "===================== Output ===================\n"\
            "Simple, local:                  %s\n"\
            "International:                  %s\n"\
            "parenthesis for negatives:      %s\n"\
            "fixed width (6 digits):         %s\n"\
            "fill character '*':             %s\n"\
            "-- note fill characters don't\n"\
            "-- count where the thousdands\n"\
            "-- separator would go:\n"\
            "filling with 9 characters:      %s\n"\
            "Suppress thousands separators:  %s\n"\
            "================================================\n",
            simple_local, international, parenthesis_for_neg,
            specified_width, fill_6_stars, fill_9_stars,
            suppress_thousands);

    /** free(money_string); */
    return 0;
}
```

```
===================== Output ===================
Simple, local:                  $1,234.57
International:                  USD1,234.57
parenthesis for negatives:      $1,234.57
fixed width (6 digits):          $  1,234.57
fill character '*':              $**1,234.57
-- note fill characters don't
-- count where the thousdands
-- separator would go:
filling with 9 characters:       $*****1,234.57
Suppress thousands separators:   $****1234.57
================================================
```

Comment: It's also a POSIX function — [`strfmon()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strfmon.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a C function to do that, but you could just write your own? Say `float price = 23234.45`. First print `(int)price` with commas, print a decimal point; then for the decimal part, do `printf("%d", (int)(price*100)%100);`

Answer (score 0):

```
int anio, base = 1e4;
double cantidad, rata = 0.5;
int din_buf = 16;
char dinero[din_buf];
printf("%3s%23s\n", "Año", "Cantidad a depositar");

setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");

for ( anio = 1; anio < 11; anio++) {
    cantidad = base * pow(rata + 1, anio);
    strfmon(dinero, din_buf, "%#6n", cantidad);
    printf("%3d\t%s\n", anio, dinero);
}
```

Comment: You should give some explanations with the code. Answer with raw code like this one are not as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows users (with MSVC)

You cannot use:

- the POSIX `printf()` formatting extras in [Cal Norum’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11695126/2706707).
- the GNU `strfmon()` function in [rreagan3’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57022809/2706707) and [Edgar Fernando Dagar’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75393968/2706707) answers.

You are kind of stuck using the Win32 API:

- [`GetCurrencyFormatEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getcurrencyformatex) for locale-dependent currency formatting
- ([`GetNumberFormatEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getnumberformatex) for locale-dependent general-purpose number formatting)

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
  double money = 1234567.89;
  wchar_t s[20], money_s[20];
  swprintf( s, sizeof s, L"%.2f", money );
  GetCurrencyFormatEx( L"en_US", 0, s, NULL, money_s, (int)sizeof money_s );
  printf( "You are owed %S!\n", money_s );
}
```

```
You are owed $1,234,567.89!
```

As always, watch your rounding errors with `swprintf()` if you are counting currency with more precision than 100<sup>ths</sup>. (You may not want to round *up* if you *owe* money.)