# Represent numeric value with typical dollar amount format

Tags: r

I have a data frame storing the dollar amount, it looks like this

```
> a
  cost
1 1e+05
2 2e+05
```

I would like it can be shown as this

```
> a  
  cost
1 $100,000
2 $200,000
```

How to do that in R?

Comment: What you have you tried so far?

Comment: Create a class and a `print` method.

Answer (score 50):

```
DF <- data.frame(cost=c(1e4, 2e5))

#assign a class    
oldClass(DF$cost) <- c("money", oldClass(DF$cost))

#S3 print method for the class    
print.money <- function(x, ...) {
  print.default(paste0("$", formatC(as.numeric(x), format="f", digits=2, big.mark=",")))
}

#format method, which is necessary for formating in a data.frame   
format.money  <- function(x, ...) {
  paste0("$", formatC(as.numeric(x), format="f", digits=2, big.mark=","))
}

DF
#         cost
#1  $10,000.00
#2 $200,000.00
```

Answer (score 33):

This will get you everything except the commas:

```
> sprintf("$%.2f", seq(100,100000,by=10000)/7)
 [1] "$14.29"    "$1442.86"  "$2871.43"  "$4300.00"  "$5728.57"  "$7157.14"  "$8585.71"  "$10014.29" "$11442.86" "$12871.43"
```

Getting those is pretty complicated, as shown in these questions:

- [How can I format currency with commas in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694901/how-can-i-format-currency-with-commas-in-c)
- [How to format a number from 1123456789 to 1,123,456,789 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449805/how-to-format-a-number-from-1123456789-to-1-123-456-789-in-c?lq=1)

Luckily, this is implemented in the [**scales** package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scales/scales.pdf):

```
library('scales')
> dollar_format()(c(100, 0.23, 1.456565, 2e3))
## [1] "$100.00"   "$0.23"     "$1.46"     "$2,000.00"
> dollar_format()(c(1:10 * 10))
## [1] "$10"  "$20"  "$30"  "$40"  "$50"  "$60"  "$70"  "$80"  "$90"  "$100"
> dollar(c(100, 0.23, 1.456565, 2e3))
## [1] "$100.00"   "$0.23"     "$1.46"     "$2,000.00"
> dollar(c(1:10 * 10))
## [1] "$10"  "$20"  "$30"  "$40"  "$50"  "$60"  "$70"  "$80"  "$90"  "$100"
> dollar(10^(1:8))
## [1] "$10"          "$100"         "$1,000"       "$10,000"      "$100,000"     "$1,000,000"   "$10,000,000"  "$100,000,000"
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `currency()` function from the `formattable` package. With OP's example

```
a <- data.frame(cost = c(1e+05, 2e+05))
a
```

> ```
>    cost
> 1 1e+05
> 2 2e+05
> ```

```
library(formattable)
a$cost <- currency(a$cost, digits = 0L)
a
```

> ```
>       cost
> 1 $100,000
> 2 $200,000
> ```

By default, 2 digits after the decimal point are shown. This has been overruled using the `digits` parameter to meet OP's expectations.

The benfit of `formattable` is that numbers are still numbers even with a format attached, e.g.,

```
a$cost2 <- 2 * a$cost
a
```

> ```
>       cost    cost2
> 1 $100,000 $200,000
> 2 $200,000 $400,000
> ```

Answer (score 4):

A very simple way is

```
library(priceR)
values <- c(1e5, 2e5)
format_dollars(values)

# [1] "$100,000" "$200,000"
```

#### Notes

- Add decimal places with `format_dollars(values, 2)` i.e.
  `"$100,000.00" "$200,000.00"`
- For other currencies use `format_currency(values, "€")` which gives `"€100,000" "€200,000"` etc