# Implementing basic arithmetic in S4 class object

Tags: r, class, r-s4

I'm creating a S4 object of the *money* class in the following manner:

```
# Create class ------------------------------------------------------------

# Create S4 class object holding money and export to generator function
setClass(Class = "money",
         slots = list(currency = "character",
                      value = "numeric")) -> money
```

For which I'm later defining the *show* method:

```
# Methods -----------------------------------------------------------------

# Create show method
setMethod("show",
          "money",
          function(object) {
              cat(switch(object@currency,
                         GBP = intToUtf8(163)),
                  format(
                      x = round(object@value, 2),
                      trim = TRUE,
                      big.mark = ",",
                      big.interval = 3
                  ),
                  sep = "")
          })
```

## Preview

So far it works as promised:

```
# Create test object
tst_fig <- new(Class = "money",
               value = 1e6,
               currency = "GBP")

# Show the object
tst_fig
# £1,000,000
```

## Problem

I would like to enable basic arithmetic on that object:

```
>> tst_fig + 1e6
Error in tst_fig + 1000000 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

### Desired results

```
> tst_fig + 1e6
# £2,000,000
```

### Attempts

Naturally this is won't work:

```
>> setMethod("+",
...           "money",
...           function(object, x) {
...               object@value + x
...           })
Error in conformMethod(signature, mnames, fnames, f, fdef, definition) : 
  in method for ‘+’ with signature ‘e1="money"’: formal arguments (e1 = "money", e2 = "money") omitted in the method definition cannot be in the signature
```

---

## Side notes

There is a similar [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22071182/1655567) provided by [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) on implementing money class in S3; in the context of this question I'm interested in creating S4 class that would behave in a similar manner without any specific reason other than curiosity. The key requirements is that **`isS4()`** on that object returns **`TRUE`**.

### What I mean by *similar manner*:

*It prints like nicely formatted money but permits all operations the one could do on a common numeric.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across how to do this in my own question [here](/questions/34207995/how-to-define-s4-method-for-taking-the-opposite-of-the-object).  I have generally used the `setMethod('Arith')` approach as it is more concise when you intend to implement several operations.  If you search the documentation `?Arith` you will see that it list the different operations as well as other S4 group generics.

As the error suggests you need to have `e1` and `e2` defined for `Arith` methods.  In your specific case the following works.

**Note** - to get your desired output (i.e. a `money` class object) you will need to create a new `money` object.

```
setMethod("+", 
    c(e1="money", e2="numeric"), 
    function(e1, e2){
        new(Class = "money", value = e1@value + e2, currency = e1@currency)
    }
)

tst_fig + 1e6
[1] £2e+06
```

However, as I said, you probably want the more general, concise version which uses `.Generic` to interpret the `Arith` method you are using.

```
setMethod("Arith", 
    c(e1="money", e2="numeric"),
    function(e1, e2)
    {
        op = .Generic[[1]]
        switch(op,
            `+` = return(new(Class = "money", value = e1@value + e2, currency = e1@currency))
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: As implemented, this still only works for `+`. You can actually call `op(e1@value, e2)` and it will work for all `op` (though it is advised to check `nargs(op)` first and call `op(e1@value)` if that is 1 instead of 2)

Comment: @JDL you are correct that it still only works for `+`.  That is intentional.  This basically allows the user complete control over the logic for each method.  I'm not sure how it could be more concise.  If you have another approach, please feel free to answer as well.  It may make a lot of my own code more concise if so.