# R: format currency on tooltip using ggplotly or plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm making a plot, first in ggplot and then making it interactive with ggplotly.

But I need that the tooltip for currect price, called "precio_actual" in data.frame  to be correctly formated.

**It appears as**: 1499 in tooltip.

**Should be**: S/ 1,4900.00.

> I'm reading the [documentation for ggplotly](https://rdrr.io/cran/plotly/man/ggplotly.html), but cannot find any
>   indication on how to achieve this.

**data**:

```
dput(tail_tvs)
structure(list(ecommerce = c("wong", "wong", "wong", "wong", 
"wong", "wong"), marca = c("sony", "samsung", "sony", "samsung", 
"daewoo", "samsung"), producto = c("sony smart tv 55'' 4k uhd kd-55x750f android", 
"samsung smart tv curvo 65'' 4k uhd 65nu7300", "sony smart tv 40'' full hd kdl-40w655d linux", 
"samsung smart tv 55'' 4k uhd 55mu6103", "daewoo smart tv 43'' full hd l43s780bts", 
"samsung smart tv 49'' 4k uhd 49mu6400"), precio_antes = c(4499, 
4999, 1699, 3599, 1439, 3999), precio_actual = c(2199, 4999, 
1299, 3599, 1439, 3999), pulgadas = c(55, 65, 40, 55, 43, 49), 
    unidades = c(2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2), descuento = c(-0.51122471660369, 
    0, -0.235432607416127, 0, 0, 0), rango = c("S/.1500 - S/.2500", 
    "> S/.4,500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", "S/.3500 - S/.4500", "S/.500 - S/.1500", 
    "S/.3500 - S/.4500")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**code:**

```
tt10 <- "Precio de televisores según su tamaño (pulgadas)"
stt10 <- "\n"


pulgadas_precio <- ggplot(tail_tvs, aes(x = pulgadas, y = precio_actual)) + 
                    geom_point(aes(color=marca),size = 4,alpha = 0.6) +
                    facet_grid(~ ecommerce) +
                    theme_ipsum_rc(grid = "Y") +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey10",size=10,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
                          axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey10",size=10,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain"),  
                          axis.title.x = element_text(colour="grey40",size=16,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=0,face="plain"),
                          axis.title.y = element_text(colour="grey40",size=16,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
                          plot.title = element_text(size = 24,vjust=4, face="bold"),
                          plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust=2, size = 16),
                          plot.caption = element_text(vjust=2, size = 16),
                          legend.title = element_text(colour="grey40",size=14,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="bold"),
                          legend.text = element_text(colour="grey10", size=18, face="plain"),
                          strip.text.x = element_text(size = 18, angle = 0),
                          strip.text.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
                          legend.position = "none") +
                    scale_y_continuous(label=comma, limits = c(0,50000)) +
                    scale_x_continuous(label=comma, limits = c(0,100)) +
                    labs(title = tt10, subtitle = stt10, caption = cptn,
                         x = "pulgadas \n", y = "precio en S/. \n") +
                    scale_color_discrete(name="marcas de tvs") +
                    geom_smooth()


ggplotly(pulgadas_precio, tooltip=c("marca", "pulgadas", "precio_actual"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered you can use a `text` argument in `aes`, and do the following:

```
ggplot(tail_tvs, aes(x = pulgadas, y = precio_actual, text = sprintf("S/ %s", comma(precio_actual))))
```

**Notice I'm formatting the `S/` part and the `comma separetor` for thousends in this text argument.**

Now when calling ggplotly, instead of

```
ggplotly(pulgadas_precio, tooltip=c("marca", "pulgadas", "precio_actual"))
```

You call you text argument, instead of the original variable:

```
ggplotly(pulgadas_precio, tooltip=c("marca", "pulgadas", "text"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately your code doesn't run, so I can't write a solution for you and test it, BUT...

You will want to pass a formatted string as presented in
[this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770799/date-format-in-tooltip-of-ggplotly).

For special currency formatting, I recommend writing your own function e.g. mycurrency(x) that returns a formatted string of the value you pass it. Use it as proposed below.

```
# draw the line plot using ggplot
gg <-ggplot(plotbycity, aes(x = date, y = rent, group = city, color = city,
    text = paste('Rent:', mycurrency(rent),
                 '<br>Date: ', as.Date(date),
                 '<br>Obs: ', count))) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle("Monthly Rents")

p <- ggplotly(gg, tooltip = c("text"))
```

See below an example of a simple currency formatting method (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070777/represent-numeric-value-with-typical-dollar-amount-format))

```
mycurrency <- function(x){
  return(paste("$", formatC(as.numeric(x), format="f", digits=2, big.mark=",")))
}
```