# I'm getting NAs introduced by coercion when i try to convert a factor column to numeric

Tags: r, data-manipulation

```
head(data$`Brand Value`)
#[1] $145.3 B $69.3 B  $65.6 B  $56 B    $49.8 B  $39.5 B 
#77 Levels: $10.4 B $10.5 B $10.6 B $11 B ... $9.6 B

data$`Brand Value`<-as.numeric(as.character(data$`Brand Value`))
#Warning message:  
#NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: None of those values is coercible to numeric. They all have non-digit characters like `$` or `B`.

Comment: Try `data$``Brand Value``<-as.numeric(gsub("[^\\.[:digit:]]", "", x))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, your data has a **dollar sign and a "B" letter** (Billion) on it (which is a character), that's the reason why you can't coerce it into a numeric data. You need to get rid of any characters or symbols if you want to change the data type into numeric. However, if you want to add a dollar sign in front of numeric data, you might want to refer to
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070777/represent-numeric-value-with-typical-dollar-amount-format)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr` which will extract only the numeric substring from the column and convert the class

```
library(readr)
data$`Brand Value` <- parse_number(data$`Brand Value`)
```