# How can I put in currency with commas in C?

Tags: c, formatting

I'm looking to format a double or long double for currency in C. I would like to place a dollar sign at the beginning, a negative if needed, commas iterating every third digit before decimal, and a dot immediately before decimal. So far, I have been printing numbers like so:

```
printf("Please enter an amount: $%.2Lf\n", money);
```

Which returns something like

```
Please enter an amount: $123456789.00
```

Numbers should look like this...

```
$123,456,789.00
$1,234.56
$123.45
```

I need it to work with any number. It would help if answers were actual code because I am relatively new at coding (freshman in college), but I know that might seem like the easy way out, so if anyone would like explaining it to me and walking me through I would greatly appreciate that too. This question was asked by someone before me on this site, but I need some serious help.

Thanks!

Comment: What type is `money`?  Is it `long double`?

Comment: This is a hard problem. To first approximation, `money` should be a `double`, but I would use a library for any serious programme.

Comment: I would convert `money` to string, then insert `,` every three chars before comma manually. I see no easy (reliable) way to do it with `printf`.

Comment: It can be either a double or long double. Our professor wants us to stay away from floats because those are things we already learned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format currency with commas in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694901/how-can-i-format-currency-with-commas-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this code snippet will help you. It's using locales for your purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    long double money;
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.UTF-8"); // Use thousands separators

    printf("How much? ");
    scanf("%Lf", &money);
    printf("Formatted: $%'.2Lf\n", money); // Notice the ' character
}
```

Locales are pretty much what they sound like. They handle *local* standards, like default format of time. When you use `setlocal` you send a *category* and a *locale* as argument. The categories are these:

- LC_ALL   selects the entire C locale
- LC_COLLATE   selects the collation category of the C locale
- LC_CTYPE     selects the character classification category of the C locale
- LC_MONETARY  selects the monetary formatting category of the C locale
- LC_NUMERIC   selects the numeric formatting category of the C locale
- LC_TIME  selects the time formatting category of the C locale

There are many different locales. en_US.UTF-8 is one of them.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/LC_categories

Comment: With 12345 that writes `Formatted: $12 345,00` for me, so space have to replaced by ',' and ',' by '.' (I am in France)

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me what locale does in this instance, I've never been taught what that does?

Comment: `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");` --> Not quite. `""` is very locale dependent.  ("" for locale specifies the locale-specific native environment)

Comment: @chux Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @DinoSalihovic Added some explanation now, but a full explanation is out of scope on an answer to this question. :)

Comment: @Broman probably but I do not have english on my raspberrypi, only C / C.UTF-8 / fr_FR.utf8 and POSIX, so I cannot test ^^

Comment: @bruno Huh? You say that you have en_US.UTF-8 and that's the one I'm using? How can you not test then?

Comment: @Broman no I do *not* have it, and strangely `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` then `sudo update-locale` change nothing. OH sorry my previous answer was wrong, bad copy past, I edited

Comment: @Broman So for class we are using repl.it which is an online compiler. The thousands separator still is not showing up. Could it be that that the online compiler just is not supporting the ' thousands separator?

Comment: @Broman Thanks for the explanation, I figured it was not super in depth but I was just curious so I appreciate it!

Comment: @Broman Where do I do that? And two, can you check out my comment to you? Thanks!

Comment: @DinoSalihovic I believe that the locale you want to use must be installed on your computer. If `en_US.UTF-8` does not work, try to find which locales that are installed and use one of those, but google to see how it handles thousand separators.

Comment: @DinoSalihovic If you don't know how to find which locales that are installed, then you can just google to find locales that do what you want and then try them in your code to find one that works.

Comment: @Broman Alrighty, I'll undo it then. Would you mind fixing it? Or helping me to the solution?