# How do you add spaces in numbers, grouping in thousands?

Tags: c

For example, if given the number 500000 or 2300000, I need to print it as 500 000 and 2 300 000

Comment: You can write a loop from the end to the begining of the number, with a counter variable, and each three printed values you print a space and reset the counter.

Comment: Alternative - you could print numbers with commas separating every 3 using <locale.h> Read more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449805/how-to-format-a-number-from-1123456789-to-1-123-456-789-in-c

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/iOYPcM)

Answer (score 0):

If your locale is configured that way and you don't mind limiting your code to POSIX, try the `printf` `'` flag.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
printf("%'d\n", 50000);
```