# Add comma in a sprintf function

Tags: c++, c

I was looking at topic: [How to format a number from 1123456789 to 1,123,456,789 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449805/how-to-format-a-number-from-1123456789-to-1-123-456-789-in-c)

So I mounted my code based on an existing one.

```
void printfcomma(char *buf, const char* text int n) {
    if (n < 1000) {
        sprintf(buf, "%s %d", text, n);
        return;
    }
    printfcomma(buf, n / 1000);
    sprintf(buf, "%s ,%03d", text, n %1000);
    return;
}
```

sprintf is only returning the final 3 digits. Example: **,536**

Does anyone have any idea why they are not showing the other numbers

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. You call `printfcomma(buf, n / 1000);` but your function is written `void printfcomma(char *buf) {`...

Comment: Sorry error when passing code to post, I edited,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting.

You should do `sprintf(s+ strlen(s),"abcde");`

```
void printfcomma(char *buf,int n) {
    if (n < 1000) {
        sprintf(buf+strlen(buf), "%d", n);
        return;
    }
    printfcomma(buf, n / 1000);
    sprintf(buf+strlen(buf), ",%03d", n %1000);
    return;
}
```

In calling function

```
memset(s,0,sizeof(s));// s is the char array.
printfcomma(s,100000536);
```

#### Output

`100,000,536`

Comment: I understand, now you can explain to me something else, I want to expand this function look at the topic. Example if I add a `%s` it me printa it 3x, so `test: ,536` ` test: ,000` ` test: 100`

Comment: @carolzinha.: As far as I know this is another separate question. But looking at the code I can see it can be reused. You can try to understand this and reuse. This answer solves your problem.For other question if you don't understand ask a seperate question after you have tried enough.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by [@coderredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165643/2410359), code is over-writing `buf`.

An alternative to calling `strlen()` is to take advantage of the return value of `sprintf()`.

> The `sprintf` function returns the number of characters written in the array, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred.  C11dr §7.21.6.6 3

Further: code should handle negative numbers too.

`const char* text` use is unclear.  Example code below does not use it.

```
int printfcomma(char *buf, int n) {
  if (n > -1000 && n < 1000) { // avoid (abs(n) < 1000) here.  abs(INT_MIN) is a problem
    return sprintf(buf, "%d", n);
  }

  int len = printfcomma(buf, n / 1000);
  if (len > 0) {
    len += sprintf(buf + len, ",%03d", text, abs(n % 1000));  // do not print `-`
  } 
  return len;
}
```

Usage

```
char s[sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT]; // Somehow, insure buffer size is sufficient.
printfcomma(s, INT_MIN);
puts(s); --> -2,147,483,648
```