# Format Integer With Comma Using Python Printf

Tags: python, string, printf, streamlit

I am using a [third party package](https://docs.streamlit.io/api.html#streamlit.slider) called streamlit and one of the APIs can draw a slider in the browser according to this:

```
streamlit.slider(label, min_value=None, max_value=None, value=None, step=None, format=None, key=None)
```

The slider that I've created can take on integer values (i.e., 1,000,000 or 10,000, etc)and this function above has an optional argument that can format this integer using `printf`:

```
format (str or None) – A printf-style format string controlling how the interface should display numbers. This does not impact the return value. 
Valid formatters: %d %e %f %g %i
```

For an integer, `1000000`, I could set the printf style formatting as `format="%d"` but I want the output to look like `1,000,000`. I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to accomplish this given the available formatting constraints.

Comment: Can you show how are you using this `format` argument?

Comment: Do you really need to use that third party package for getting the job done? Or are you fine with other formatting approach?

Comment: @Saimon, `streamlit` is not for that. Is a library framework for building Machine Learning and Data Science beautiful apps that can be seen on the browser with instant update on parameter modifications

Comment: Sorry, printf style formatting doesn't support what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `big_number = 100000`.

In `python 3.7` you can do something like this:

```
print(f"{big_number:,d}")
```

In older versions:

```
print('{:,d}'.format(big_number))
```

And the output will be:

```
100,000
```

I am assuming you want this behavior on the `range` values of the `streamlit.slider()`. Well, according to `streamlit` documentation as you stated on your question:

> `format` (`str` or `None`) – A `printf`-style format string controlling how
>   the interface should display numbers. This does not impact the return
>   value. Valid formatters: `%d` `%e` `%f` `%g` `%i`

So, it seems it does not support the whole `printf`-style specification, just those formatters without [flags](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sprintf.html).

Even in the `python` [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
they have to set some flags to achieve this when using `str.format()`:

> Note
>
> When formatting a number (`int`, `float`, `complex`, `decimal.Decimal` and
>   `subclasses`) with the `n` type (ex: `'{:n}'.format(1234)`), the function
>   temporarily sets the `LC_CTYPE` locale to the `LC_NUMERIC` locale to
>   decode `decimal_point` and `thousands_sep` fields of `localeconv()` if they
>   are non-ASCII or longer than 1 byte, and the `LC_NUMERIC` locale is
>   different than the `LC_CTYPE` locale. This temporary change affects
>   other threads.

This is consistent with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11695246/5206417)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.format() method, available in python to carry out this task.