# How to add dot on C numbers

Tags: c, function, dot

I have function ticketVipCounter to calculate prices

```
int ticketVipCounter( int ticketVip ){
    return ticketVip * 250000;
}

printf("Prices Is: %d", ticketVipCounter(4));
```

If i run the code,
The result will be 1000000
How do i change the code so the result will be 1.000.000, any idea?, Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

See this similar question:

[How to format a number from 1123456789 to 1,123,456,789 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449805/how-to-format-a-number-from-1123456789-to-1-123-456-789-in-c)

It looks like if your printf supports POSIX 2008, you can set a locale and use the `'` flag.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");
    printf("%'d\n", 1123456789);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I tried it, but the output is " `d ", I copied all of your code and run it but it still didn't work

Comment: If you follow the link I posted, the second answer gives a way to implement your own "printfcomma" function which you could adapt to your locale.

It could be that your printf doesn't support POSIX 2008, and so doesn't recognise the ```'``` flag

Comment: Thankyou very much