# How to divide digits by thousands in Printf function

Tags: c++, format

I have a C++ `printf` function and I need to divide int or double to thousands digits (per 3 digits), like this:

```
56 655 666.566
```

What if formatstring for this?

```
printf("%.3f",56655666.566)
```

prints only:

```
56655666.566
```

Comment: [Should be the same way you do it in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449805/4581301)

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using the old C function `printf` when programming in C++?

Comment: I need it really for Autodesk ARX function, for formating a table cell. ARX use the same formated string as C. I wrote "Printf" for simplify question,

Answer (score 0):

The proper sollution is this:

```
 //Make sure output buffer is big enough and that input is a valid null terminated string
bool pretty_number(const wchar_t *input, wchar_t *output)
{
  if(wcslen(input) >= wcslen(output)) //general checking of buffer size
      return false;
  int pos = 0; //index in output
  if(input[0] == L'+' || input[0] == L'-')
      output[0] = input[0], input++, ++pos;
  int iIntPartLen = wcslen(input);
  for(; iIntPartLen > 0; --iIntPartLen) //find '.'
      if(input[iIntPartLen] == L'.' || input[iIntPartLen] == L',')
          break;
  if(iIntPartLen == 0) iIntPartLen = wcslen(input); //tečka nenalezena

  //first int part
  int i = 0;
  for(; i < iIntPartLen; ++i, ++pos) //i .. input position, pos .. output position
  {
      if((iIntPartLen - i) % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
      {
          output[pos++] = L' ';
      }

      output[pos] = input[i];
  }
  //second decimal part
  if(input[i] == L'.' || input[i] == L',')
  {
      output[pos] = input[i];
      ++iIntPartLen; //přeskočit tečku
      for(; i < wcslen(input); ++i, ++pos) //i .. input position, pos .. output position
      {
          if((i - iIntPartLen) % 3 == 0 && (i - iIntPartLen) != 0)
          {
              output[pos++] = L' ';
          }

          output[pos] = input[i];
      }
  }

 output[pos] = '\0';
```

}