# openpyxl - adjust column width size

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have following script which is converting a CSV file to an XLSX file, but my column size is very narrow. Each time I have to drag them with mouse to read data. Does anybody know how to set column width in `openpyxl`?

Here is the code I am using.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import csv
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

f = open('users_info_cvs.txt', "rU")

csv.register_dialect('colons', delimiter=':')

reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='colons')

wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = r"account_info.xlsx"

ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.title = "Users Account Information"

for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
    for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
        column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index + 1))
        ws.cell('%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))).value = cell

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721232/importerror-cannot-import-name-get-column-letter

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You could estimate (or use a mono width font) to achieve this. Let's assume data is a nested array like

```
[['a1','a2'],['b1','b2']]
```

We can get the max characters in each column. Then set the width to that. Width is exactly the width of a monospace font (if not changing other styles at least). Even if you use a variable width font it is a decent estimation. This will not work with formulas.

```py
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

column_widths = []
for row in data:
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
        if len(column_widths) > i:
            if len(cell) > column_widths[i]:
                column_widths[i] = len(cell)
        else:
            column_widths += [len(cell)]
    
for i, column_width in enumerate(column_widths,1):  # ,1 to start at 1
    worksheet.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i)].width = column_width
```

A bit of a hack but your reports will be more readable.

Comment: Might you have an idea what's the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642026/column-widths-of-some-columns-in-openpyxl-become-zero-after-60-columns

Comment: when I have int as a cell value, this will bump into an error since int has no len property, is there a way to avoid this? thanks!

Comment: @KevinZhao A little late - but your question is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189800/length-of-an-integer-in-python

Comment: might be usefull to add that you still need to save the workbook with `wb.save(filename = dest_filename)`

Comment: This fails in version 3.0.9 (and likely before) on `len(cell)`, with TypeError `object of type 'Cell' has no len()`

Comment: @IndianaBones you can replace len(cell) with len(str(cell)) to avoid that error.

Comment: @Tyler you should just do ```cell.value``` instead. No need to typecast it to a string. So ```len(cell.value)``` that is unless you have integers then you would typecast it.

Answer (score 95):

My variation of Bufke's answer. Avoids a bit of branching with the array and ignores empty cells / columns.

Now fixed for non-string cell values.

```
ws = your current worksheet
dims = {}
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value:
            dims[cell.column] = max((dims.get(cell.column, 0), len(str(cell.value))))    
for col, value in dims.items():
    ws.column_dimensions[col].width = value
```

As of openpyxl version 3.0.3 you need to use

```py
 dims[cell.column_letter] = max((dims.get(cell.column_letter, 0), len(str(cell.value))))
```

as the openpyxl library will raise a TypeError if you pass `column_dimensions` a number instead of a column letter, everything else can stay the same.

Comment: line 6 can be improved to use column letter: dims[cell.column_letter] = max((dims.get(cell.column_letter, 0), len(str(cell.value))))

Comment: Also worth remembering this will make cells longer for formulae, so you could add a check it doesn't start with "=" before updating the length

Answer (score 57):

Even more pythonic way to set the width of all columns that works at least in openpyxl version 2.4.0:

```
for column_cells in worksheet.columns:
    length = max(len(as_text(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    worksheet.column_dimensions[column_cells[0].column].width = length
```

The as_text function should be something that converts the value to a proper length string, like for Python 3:

```
def as_text(value):
    if value is None:
        return ""
    return str(value)
```

Comment: `def as_text(value):
    return str(value) if value is not None else ""`

Comment: @thorhunter `len(cell.value or "") `, no need for extra functions

Comment: @IrinaVelikopolskaya if cell.value does not implement `__len__`, this will throw exception (`int` or `NoneType` for example)

Comment: @thorhunter, you're right about `int`, haven't thought about that. But `NoneType` would cause no trouble, since `None or ""` is an empty string

Comment: @IrinaVelikopolskaya datetime is another example of where one gets an exception. The as_text function seems to work best for me.

Comment: `length = max(map(lambda cell: len(str(cell.value)) if cell.value else 0, column_cells))` - better for me, pythonically clear and short

Comment: @bl79 That way the length of 0 is 0, when it should be 1. Probably rarely a problem though.

Comment: Note that with openpyxl 2.6, this code will crash with `TypeError: expected <class 'str'>`. One has to specify a column name now, i.e. `ws.column_dimensions[openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column)].width = length`.See  https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1240/typeerror-raised-when-try-to-change-the

Comment: @IrinaVelikopolskaya, your code could be complemented with this: `len(str(cell.value or ""))`

Comment: This also works for me as a shorter version of @phihag comment (I'm using openpyxl 3.1.2): ws.column_dimensions[column_cells[0].column_letter].width = length

Answer (score 42):

With openpyxl 3.0.3 the best way to modify the columns is with the [DimensionHolder](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html) object, which is a dictionary that maps each column to a [ColumnDimension](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html) object.
ColumnDimension can get parameters as [bestFit](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html#openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.ColumnDimension.bestFit), [auto_size](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html#openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.ColumnDimension.auto_size) (which is an alias of bestFit) and [width](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html#openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.ColumnDimension.width).
Personally, auto_size doesn't work as expected and I had to use width and figured out that the best width for the column is `len(cell_value) * 1.23`.

To get the value of each cell it's necessary to iterate over each one, but I personally didn't use it because in my project I just had to write worksheets, so I got the longest string in each column directly on my data.

The example below just shows how to modify the column dimensions:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import ColumnDimension, DimensionHolder
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Example.xslx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

dim_holder = DimensionHolder(worksheet=ws)

for col in range(ws.min_column, ws.max_column + 1):
    dim_holder[get_column_letter(col)] = ColumnDimension(ws, min=col, max=col, width=20)

ws.column_dimensions = dim_holder
```

Comment: This seems to have worked the best for me, whereas the other answers were not properly adjusting all.  Worked even with merged cells.

Answer (score 10):

I have a problem with merged_cells and autosize not work correctly, if you have the same problem, you can solve with the next code:

```
for col in worksheet.columns:
    max_length = 0
    column = col[0].column # Get the column name
    for cell in col:
        if cell.coordinate in worksheet.merged_cells: # not check merge_cells
            continue
        try: # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
            if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                max_length = len(cell.value)
        except:
            pass
    adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
    worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a more general, simplified solution for users new to the topic (Not specified for the question).

If you want to change the width or the height of cells in `openpyxl` (Version 3.0.9), you can do it simply by assigning the attributes of the cells with `row_dimensions` or `column_dimensions`.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb["Sheet"]


sheet["A1"] = "Tall row"
sheet["B2"] = "Wide column"

# Change height of row A1
sheet.row_dimensions[1].height = 100
# Change width of column B
sheet.column_dimensions["B"].width = 50

wb.save("StackOverflow.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 9):

A slight improvement of the above accepted answer, that I think is more pythonic (asking for forgiveness is better than asking for permission)

```
column_widths = []
for row in workSheet.iter_rows():
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
        try:
            column_widths[i] = max(column_widths[i], len(str(cell.value)))
        except IndexError:
            column_widths.append(len(str(cell.value)))

for i, column_width in enumerate(column_widths):
    workSheet.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i + 1)].width = column_width
```

Comment: Need to consider if cell.value is not a string. For instance, if cell.value is of float type, type casting will be needed

Comment: wow that was 4 years ago. You are correct though I edited to fix. Just added a cast to string.

Comment: Even more pythonic would be to use a `defaultdict` instead of an `if` or a `try`/`except IndexError` and `.items()` rather than `enumerate`.

Answer (score 9):

We can convert numbers to their ASCII values and give it to column_dimension parameter

```
import openpyxl as xl

work_book = xl.load_workbook('file_location')
sheet = work_book['Sheet1']
column_number = 2
column = str(chr(64 + column_number))
sheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 20
work_book.save('file_location')
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my version referring @Virako 's code snippet

```
def adjust_column_width_from_col(ws, min_row, min_col, max_col):

        column_widths = []

        for i, col in \
                enumerate(
                    ws.iter_cols(min_col=min_col, max_col=max_col, min_row=min_row)
                ):

            for cell in col:
                value = cell.value
                if value is not None:

                    if isinstance(value, str) is False:
                        value = str(value)

                    try:
                        column_widths[i] = max(column_widths[i], len(value))
                    except IndexError:
                        column_widths.append(len(value))

        for i, width in enumerate(column_widths):

            col_name = get_column_letter(min_col + i)
            value = column_widths[i] + 2
            ws.column_dimensions[col_name].width = value
```

And how to use is as follows,

```
adjust_column_width_from_col(ws, 1,1, ws.max_column)
```

Answer (score 4):

All the above answers are generating an issue which is that col[0].column is returning number while worksheet.column_dimensions[column] accepts only character such as 'A', 'B', 'C' in place of column. I've modified @Virako's code and it is working fine now.

```
import re
import openpyxl
..
for col in _ws.columns:
    max_lenght = 0
    print(col[0])
    col_name = re.findall('\w\d', str(col[0]))
    col_name = col_name[0]
    col_name = re.findall('\w', str(col_name))[0]
    print(col_name)
    for cell in col:
        try:
            if len(str(cell.value)) > max_lenght:
                max_lenght = len(cell.value)
        except:
            pass
    adjusted_width = (max_lenght+2)
    _ws.column_dimensions[col_name].width = adjusted_width
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1171/

Answer (score 4):

Another approach without storing any state could be like this:

```
from itertools import chain
# Using `ws` as the Worksheet
for cell in chain.from_iterable(ws.iter_cols()):
    if cell.value:
        ws.column_dimensions[cell.column_letter].width = max(
            ws.column_dimensions[cell.column_letter].width,
            len(f"{cell.value}"),
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to change @User3759685 above answer to this when the openpxyl updated. I was getting an error. Well @phihag reported this in the comments as well

```
for column_cells in ws.columns:
    new_column_length = max(len(as_text(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    new_column_letter = (openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
    if new_column_length > 0:
        ws.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a dirty fix. But openpyxl actually supports `auto_fit`. But there is no method to access the property.

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Example.xslx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
for i in range(1, ws.max_column+1):
    ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i)].bestFit = True
    ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i)].auto_size = True
```

Comment: This does not work for me (openpyxl 3.1.2).

Answer (score 3):

When this came up for me, I just did everything I wanted to do with openpyxl, saved the workbook, and opened it again with pywin32. Pywin32 has autofit built in without having to make a bunch of rules/conditions.

Edit: I should note that pywin32 only works with Windows.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("excelFile.xlsx")

excel.Worksheets(1).Activate()
excel.ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit()

wb.Save()
wb.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

I did add a rule, however, because I had one text column that had some long values I didn't need to show. I limited any column to 75 characters.

```
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("excelFile.xlsx")

excel.Worksheets(1).Activate()
excel.ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit()

for col in excel.ActiveSheet.Columns:
    if col.ColumnWidth > 75:
        col.ColumnWidth = 75

wb.Save()
wb.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

Comment: This is the best method by far (works like a charm), however this would not work for Linux right?

Comment: @Ángel that's correct. Unfortunately, pywin32 is only for Windows. I should have added a note about that but didn't think of it at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Compiling and applying multiple suggestions above, and extending merged cells detection to the horizontally merged cells only, I could offer this code:

```
def adjust_width(ws):
    """
    Adjust width of the columns
    @param ws: worksheet
    @return: None
    """

    def is_merged_horizontally(cell):
        """
        Checks if cell is merged horizontally with an another cell
        @param cell: cell to check
        @return: True if cell is merged horizontally with an another cell, else False
        """
        cell_coor = cell.coordinate
        if cell_coor not in ws.merged_cells:
            return False
        for rng in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
            if cell_coor in rng and len(list(rng.cols)) > 1:
                return True
        return False

    for col_number, col in enumerate(ws.columns, start=1):
        col_letter = get_column_letter(col_number)

        max_length = max(
            len(str(cell.value or "")) for cell in col if not is_merged_horizontally(cell)
        )
        adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 0.95
        ws.column_dimensions[col_letter].width = adjusted_width
```

Comment: This works perfectly with one small simple change. ```adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 0.8```

Answer (score 2):

After update from openpyxl2.5.2a to latest 2.6.4 (final version for python 2.x support), I got same issue in configuring the width of a column.

Basically I always calculate the width for a column (dims is a dict maintaining each column width):

```
dims[cell.column] = max((dims.get(cell.column, 0), len(str(cell.value))))
```

Afterwards I am modifying the scale to something shortly bigger than original size, but now you have to give the "Letter" value of a column and not anymore a int value (col below is the value and is translated to the right letter):

```
worksheet.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col)].width = value +1
```

This will fix the visible error and assigning the right width to your column ;) 
Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

I made a function that is very fast with large Excel files because it uses pandas.read_excel

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

def auto_adjust_column_width(file_path, sheet_name=0):
    column_widths = []

    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=None)
    for col in df.columns:
        max_length = int(df[col].astype(str).str.len().max() * 1.2)
        column_widths.append(max_length)

    wb = load_workbook(file_path)
    if isinstance(sheet_name, int):
        sheet_name = wb.sheetnames[sheet_name]

    worksheet = wb[sheet_name]
    for i, column_width in enumerate(column_widths):
        column = get_column_letter(i+1)
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = column_width
    wb.save(file_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just insert the below code in your file:

```
# Importing the necessary modules
try:
        from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
except ImportError:
        from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
        from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

for column_cells in sheet.columns:
    new_column_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    new_column_letter = (get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
    if new_column_length > 0:
        sheet.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer for Python 3.8 and OpenPyXL 3.0.0.

I tried to avoid using the `get_column_letter` function but failed.

This solution uses the newly introduced [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) aka "walrus operator":

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("myxlfile.xlsx")

worksheet = workbook["Sheet1"]

MIN_WIDTH = 10
for i, column_cells in enumerate(worksheet.columns, start=1):
    width = (
        length
        if (length := max(len(str(cell_value) if (cell_value := cell.value) is not None else "")
                          for cell in column_cells)) >= MIN_WIDTH
        else MIN_WIDTH
    )
    worksheet.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i)].width = width
```

Comment: `max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in filter(None, column_cells))` seems clearer to me.

Comment: This `(length if length >= MIN_WIDTH else MIN_WIDTH)` can be simplified as `max(length, MIN_WIDTH)`, and so you can remove the walrus operator.

Answer (score 1):

Since in openpyxl 2.6.1, it requires the column letter, not the column number, when setting the width.

```py
 for column in sheet.columns:
    length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column)
    length = length if length <= 16 else 16
    sheet.column_dimensions[column[0].column_letter].width = length
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code calculates and adjusts widths using a specific font:

```py
# example of usage: 
# adjust_excel_column_widths(worksheet, 'calibri', 11)

import math
from PIL import ImageFont
from openpyxl import worksheet
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter

def adjust_excel_column_widths(worksheet: worksheet, fontname, fontsize):
    
    def points_to_pixels(points):
        return points * 4 / 3 # 1pnt = 4/3px

    font = ImageFont.truetype(fontname, points_to_pixels(fontsize)) 
    excel_unit_width = font.getlength('0')

    def getwidth(cell_value):
        return 0.0 if cell_value is None else font.getlength(str(cell_value))

    column_number = 0
    for column in worksheet.columns:
        column_number += 1
        column_letter = get_column_letter(column_number)
        column_width = math.ceil( max(getwidth(cell.value) for cell in column) / excel_unit_width )
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column_letter].width = column_width
```