# Using pandas dataframe style for adjusting column width

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.8, pandas.excelwriter

I have a `dataframe` df:

```
A                               B                  LongColName1     AnotherNa   AnotherName3
Brunner Island is not island    Baltimore is town  0.26             3.88        3.75
Brunner Island is not island    Baltimore is town  -0.59            1.47        2.01
```

When I dump the above dataframe to excel, it appears as following in excel:

[image]

Is there a way to style the dataframe so that dump to excel looks as following:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach could be to find the max length of column and set the width of that column explicitly while writing to excel.

Consider below dataframe:

```
In [527]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[527]: 
                                 A
0     Brunner Island is not island
1  Brunner Island is not an island

len_max = df.A.str.len().max()

from StyleFrame import StyleFrame

excel_writer = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter(filename)
sf = StyleFrame(df)
sf.set_column_width(columns=['A'],width=len_max)

sf.to_excel(excel_writer=excel_writer)
excel_writer.save()
```

Comment: A styled Dataframe doesn't have a method called "set_column_width". To my opinion this answer is not correct. this line will not work "sf.set_column_width(columns=['A'],width=len_max)"

Comment: It was there at the time when this question was asked. Has it been removed from latest pandas version?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to auto adjust column width. But there are some workarounds mentioned in this post [Is there a way to auto-adjust Excel column widths with pandas.ExcelWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326973/is-there-a-way-to-auto-adjust-excel-column-widths-with-pandas-excelwriter)