# Is there a way to set width for columns for some specific rows while using pandas Excelwriter?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

I am exporting 3 different Dataframes in a single sheet. So I would like to format my 2nd dataframe (that is in middle). I want to change it's col width. I have row number range and col number range for which I would like to change the width. But I am unable to find any function that changes width of col for specific rows. Is it possible to do so? If yes, Can someone please suggest, How can I do that.[image: Sample Excel Sheet]

Comment: _Is there a way to set width for columns for some specific rows while using [anything]_ - No

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width of **all** rows in a column via the methods suggested in:

[Is there a way to auto-adjust Excel column widths with pandas.ExcelWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326973/is-there-a-way-to-auto-adjust-excel-column-widths-with-pandas-excelwriter)

But you certainly can not change the width of the column for one specific row and keep the change in column width confined to that specific row alone.

Comment: Yes, I checked the above link previously, but that is not my objective.