# How to define dynamic column range in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel

I am using Python 3 to generate an Excel file. In each run a number of columns is different.

With static number of columns, I would use e.g.:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("File.xlsx", engine = "xlsxwriter")
writer.sheets["Sheet"].set_column("A:G", 10)
```

What is a code expression to select all Excel columns (replacing "A:G" above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of actually auto-adjusted width found [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326973/is-there-a-way-to-auto-adjust-excel-column-widths-with-pandas-excelwriter)].

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/path/to/output/file.xlsx') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheetName', index=False, na_rep='NaN')

for column in df:
    column_length = max(df[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
    col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(column)
    writer.sheets['sheetName'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_length)

writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine the shape of your data, using the integer based notation can be helpful.

```
writer.sheets["Sheet"].set_column(0,data.shape[1], 10)
```

Comment: Smart, thanks! I was about to go the way of auto-adjust as commented below: