# ImportError: cannot import name get_column_letter

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, importerror, openpyxl

I am able to use openpyxl as an import in my code. But when I try to do the following:

```
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name get_column_letter
```

I am using python 2.7. I have installed it using `easy_install`. Tried searching for this issue but couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: Are you using some `python package by the same name`? Please make sure that you are not importing any custom made python package/file by the name `get_column_letter`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The function `get_column_letter` has been relocated in Openpyxl version 2.4 from `openpyxl.cell` to `openpyxl.utils`.

The current import is: `from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter`

If you do not know which version the end-user has, you can use the following code:

```
try: 
    from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
except ImportError:
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
```

Comment: `openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(28)` worked for me. This prints 'AB' column letter.

Answer (score 1):

`from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter`

This is working for **Python3** also.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I reinstall [the latest openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/downloads) using "python setup.py install". Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(openpyxl.cell.get_column_letter(1)) # does not work …
```

You would rather use

```
print(openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Working in Python 3.8:

Once the library has been imported using

`from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter`

the alphanumeric column value can be acquired by this approach:

`print(get_column_letter(26))`

or

`column_variable =  get_column_letter(26)`

Sorry if this is too simplistic, it took me a while to realize the conversion from column index number to column letter is independent of any sheet that might be open, therefore, there's no need to use dot.methods for a worksheet or individual cell.

Answer (score -2):

**tl;dr for Python3**

- `pip3 install Cython`
- `pip3 install pandas`

Neither of the other two solutions from Abbas or Jael Woo worked for me for Python3.

I ended up using `apt-get install python3-pandas`, but then `pip3 install pandas` failed because it said I needed Cython, as it does mention in the [Pandas installation docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#optional-dependencies) that it is an "optional dependency" anyways.

That being said, I ran `pip3 install Cython` and then ran `pip3 install pandas`, and it worked.

Note: Cython and Pandas installation took a while on Ubuntu (unsure of EC2's Ubuntu version) but seemed to be much quicker on Mac 10.11.5

EDIT: using apt-get to install Pandas yielded errors because apt-get installed an older version of Pandas. Once I installed/upgraded Pandas using pip3, the *ImportErrors* were gone.

Edit: if you care enough to downvote, try adding some constructive criticism to this answer in the form of a comment