# Openpyxl module exception

Tags: python, anaconda, openpyxl

I have a python script attempting utilize openpyxl and recently have been getting the following exception:

`No module named utils`

Where it is getting thrown is in my imports section:

```
import csv
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter    <<< Throws exception
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, Font, Border, Side
```

I am utilizing Openpyxl 3.0.1 with Python 3.6 (also tried with an Anaconda environment with same result as well as 3.7). Not sure if I'm missing a dependency?

Comment: Show the output of: `print(openpyxl.__version__)`. Relevant [importerror-cannot-import-name-get-column-letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721232/importerror-cannot-import-name-get-column-letter)

Comment: `3.0.1`
`Press any key to continue . . .`

Comment: Not really relevant as I stated the versions above and the link provided is over 3 years old and a quite a few versions behind what I'm asking a question for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:
`from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter`