# Using openpyxl.utils in Python

Tags: python, import, package

At the moment I'm learning Python.
I have tried to import "from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter" but it never works.
What I have to do, so it working?
See in the picture:

[Picture from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rRn1.png)

Comment: Do you have an old version of openpyxl? As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721232/importerror-cannot-import-name-get-column-letter), `get_column_letter` was moved in version 2.4.

Comment: Thanks, I have found it was an old version

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.