# Auto-size column width

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is there way to auto-size (auto-fit) the width based on cell contents for the entire worksheet.

```
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width=number
```

I am not looking for the above, for which you have to specify the column.
Is there a way to set it up with "openpyxl"?

Comment: ***"way to auto-size (auto-fit)"***: Not implemented in `openpyxl`. Relevant [`[python][openpyxl] column width`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Bopenpyxl%5D+column+width)

Comment: You indeed could have found this yourself. It is a known – and *closed* – issue: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1275/auto_size-and-bestfit-not-working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197574/openpyxl-adjust-column-width-size

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of research finally, I found it. This code decides the best fit for the columns. I feel this answers you question because you are using the word **Auto-fit**

NOTE : In the below code, **sheet** is the worksheet name. Usually in the documentation, we can see it as **ws**. Please don't forget to change the worksheet name.

```
# Imorting the necessary modules
try:
        from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
except ImportError:
        from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
        from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook



for column_cells in sheet.columns:
    new_column_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    new_column_letter = (get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
    if new_column_length > 0:
        sheet.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23
```

UPDATE : This code doesn't work for all, but don't hesitate to try it

Answer (score -3):

If you simply want to set the width to some "number", just loop over it (to the max column), If you need to set the width for each column specifically tailored to the contents of that(!) column, I think that is not possible with openpyxl (sadly).