# Django No module named win32com?

Tags: python

I got this issue. I have to deploy my Django project from a Mac computer(OSX). But I get this error:
No module named win32com
Is there a way or alternative library?

This is where I need it:
**views.py**

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
ex = excel.Workbooks.Open(save_path)
ex_sheet = ex.Worksheets('Finansal Tablolar_formul')
ex_sheet.Columns.AutoFit()
ex_sheet_2 = ex.Worksheets('Finansal Tablolar_formul')
ex_sheet_2.Columns.AutoFit()
ex.Save()
ex.Close(True)
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Basically I need it for autofit(larger) the cells

Comment: Did you try to install pywin32 using pip?

Comment: Firstly this question doesn't even need the `django` tag. Secondly "_Is there a way or alternative library_" asking for library, tools, etc. recommendations is _off-topic_.

Comment: See this perhaps it might be helpful for you: https://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: @GaspardMerten Yes, I tried but did not work

Comment: "It did not work" is not an adequate description of the problem. Show *exactly what you did* in order to "try to install pywin32 using pip", and *exactly what happened*.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out library `openpyxl`

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Simple usage of reading workbook:

```
import openpyxl

file_path = "path to your file.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file_path, data_only=True)
sheet_obj = wb_obj['your sheet name']
# or just open the active sheet
# sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
max_col = sheet_obj.max_column

for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
    column_1 = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1).value
    column_2 = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 2).value
    column_3 = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 3).value
```

In your case, you should use `openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter` to auto fitting the cells.

You can look at below answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40935194/10515127

Comment: That isn't going to help with `sheet.Columns.AutoFit()` which was an explicit requirement of the question.