# Python: adding a column to one sheet from an excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to add just one empty column into one sheet of an excel file. The excel file that I'm using has a specific structure that I can't change. That being said the column right after where I am trying to insert has a very small width. The code I have below will not insert the column before that small column and after a standard size column. But when I adjust the index to be in between 2 standard size columns there's no issue.

How can I fix my code to not have this issue inserting a column or are there better methods?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet= workbook.worksheets[8]
sheet.inset_cols(185)
workbook.save(filename= 'file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to set the column width. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197574/openpyxl-adjust-column-width-size/14450572#14450572>

Comment: When you insert a column, openpyxl only adjusts the affected cells. Things like column widths, merged cells have to be managed in client code.