# Autofit column width in python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been trying to autofit the column width of some excel workbooks.
I found this thread:
[openpyxl - adjust column width size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197574/openpyxl-adjust-column-width-size)
And tried to use most of these methods, but none worked. I didn't get any errors, but it also wasn't creating the result I had hoped for. What would I need to do or change to autofit, or change the width of my columns so that all the text is immediately readable without having to resize the columns manually.

Thanks!

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import openpyxl

files = ['A.xlsx', 'B.xlsx', 'C.xlsx', 'D.xlsx', 'E.xlsx']
for file in files:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('exported_data/' + file)
    for sheet in range(len(wb.worksheets)):
        ws = wb.worksheets[sheet]
        for i in range(1, ws.max_column + 1):
            ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i)].bestFit = True
            ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i)].auto_size = True
```

Edit:

Problem solved! In case people find this when trying to solve a similar problem, I used xlwings as BigBen suggested in the comments.
This is the code I ended up using:

```
import xlwings as xw

files = ['A.xlsx', 'B.xlsx', 'C.xlsx', 'D.xlsx', 'E.xlsx']
for file in files:
    with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
        wb = xw.Book('exported_data/' + file)
        for sheet in range(len(wb.sheets)):
            ws = wb.sheets[sheet]
            ws.autofit()
        wb.save()
        wb.close()
```

Comment: The only reliable way to do this that I've found is either xlwings or win32com... i.e. actually interacting with an instance of Excel.

Comment: xlwings did the trick for me, thank you!