# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() - Python/Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a cookie clicker game, where there is a surface that displays how many cookies I have.

Here is my code for drawing text.

```
 def draw_text(self, text, font_name, size, color, x, y, align="nw"):
            font = pg.font.Font(font_name, size)
            text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
            text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
            self.screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
```

Then in the new function of my game loop (for when a new game starts), I created a variable:

```
def new(self):
        self.cookie_count = 0
```

And then finally, I have my drawing function.

```
def draw(self):
    self.draw_text('Cookies: {}'.format(len(self.cookie_count)), self.cookie_font, 105, SKYBLUE, 325, HEIGHT * 3/4, align="nw")
    pg.display.update()
```

Yet, when I run the program, I get:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I am new to creating a "score counter" you could call it. But why does

```
self.draw_text('Cookies: {}'.format(len(self.cookie_count))
```

give me an error? How come the length of self.cookie_count is not printed?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with `len`, but it doesn't work on `int`. `len` returns how long a string is.

Comment: `.format(self.cookie_count)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the value of `self.cookie_count`, you can just use

```
self.draw_text('Cookies: {}'.format(self.cookie_count)
```

The `len()` function returns the number of items in an object such as an array and does not work on an `int` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the `len()` function as your `self.cookie_count` is already an int.

So your answer should be:

```
self.draw_text('Cookies: {}'.format(self.cookie_count))
```

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer. A couple of good tips for you: 1) Use backticks (`) to quote functions, variables and other code snippets inline. 2) Use four spaces at the start of a line to create a code block. These tips and other useful information can be found by clicking on the help icon at the top right hand corner of the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189800/length-of-an-integer-in-python) is what you're looking for. `len()` is a container function, so `len(int)` gives an error. Use `len(str(self.cookie_count))`. Hope that helps!

EDIT: This will get you the number of digits in the integer, including a negative sign. For floats this will also count the decimal point. For small numbers (less than 10^16), it's faster to use

```
import math
digits = math.log10(n) + 1
```

but this is less readable. With large numbers, rounding imprecisions give an incorrect answer, and the simplicity of the string method far outweighs its lack of speed.

Comment: You should put the relevant information from that link in your answer, as links can become deprecated over time.

Comment: `len` is not a "string or list function", it works for anything that implements `__len__`, and that is most built-in container types.

Comment: note that your `log10` algorithm only works on positive integers.

Comment: Just a helpful tip for you - if you use backticks (`) around inline code snippets it makes your answer clearer.

Comment: @robinCTS Thanks! Totally forgot.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `self.cookie_count = 0` then its type is integer. `len()` works on lists, tuples and strings but not on integers.

Comment: Using backticks (`) around inline code snippets helps to make answers clearer.