# I'm trying to count the number of decimal digits in a positive and negative integers

Tags: python

Here is my code, its supposed to tell me the count number of the decimal digits in a positive and negative integers.

```
def num_digits(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(str(n))):
        count += n % 10
        n = n // 10
    return count


num_digits(2)
print()
print()
num_digits(12)
print()
print()
num_digits(123)
```

When I run the program I get nothing
Can you please show me the full code written correctly

Comment: You are ignoring the value returned from the function and doing empty print. Try `print(num_digits(2))`

Comment: Why not: `len(str(abs(number)))` ?

Comment: You are right now it prints a the number of digits but it adds one to them so like for print(num_digits(2)) --- it prints 2 when its supposed to print 1

Comment: ... Or assign the return value and print it: `n = num_digits(2); print(n)`.

Comment: You do understand that `print()` is just printing an empty line, right? ;)

Comment: Can you please rights the full code I'm a beginner to python

Comment: the print() is to add line breaks

Comment: `num_digits(2)` returns a value- which is not saved nor printed anywhere

Comment: add `print(f'count:{count}   n:{n}   n%10:{n%10}')` as the first line in the for loop.  It will help you visualize the process.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: I just need someone to right the full correct code and then I would see what I did wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of an integer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189800/length-of-an-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct code for your requirment

```
def num_digits(n):
    count = 0
    while n>0:
      count+=1
      n=n//10
    return count

print(num_digits(2))
print(num_digits(12))
print(num_digits(123))
```

Comment: If it's Correct let me know please

Answer (score 0):

```
def num_digits(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(str(n))):
        print(f'count:{count} n:{n} n%10:{n%10}')
        count += n % 10
        n = n // 10
    return count


num_digits(2)
print()
print()
num_digits(12)
print()
print()
num_digits(123)
```

This kind of works but I need it to be better