# Better way to compute floor of log(n,b) for integers n and b?

Tags: python

I'm looking to compute `floor(log(n,b))` where `n` and `b` are both integers. Directly implementing this function fails for even slightly large values of `n` and `b`

```
# direct implementation
def floor_log(n,b):
    return math.floor(math.log(n,b))
```

For example, `floor_log(100**3, 100)` evaluates to `2` instead of the correct value `3`.

I was able to come up with a working function which repeatedly divides until nothing remains

```
# loop based implementation
def floor_log(n,b):
    val = 0
    n = n // b
    while n > 0:
        val += 1
        n = n // b
    return val
```

is there a faster or more elegant way of obtaining this solution? Perhaps using built-in functionality?

Comment: How large/small are *n* and *b* expected to be?

Comment: @Blender Preferably I'm looking for a solution that works for all positive 32 bit integers. If you have a solution with different bounds I would also be interested in that too.

Comment: I'm not aware of such function in both Python built-in or numpy. I think if you really care about performance in this function, it would be better to implement your python version in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I posted this question. I originally accepted [trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48725949/2790047) but recently realized that it fails to consistently produce the correct result when `n` gets large. There are really two problems. First, while we can be sure that the result of `math.floor(math.log(n, b))` is not going be off by more than one as long as `n < 2**(2**53)` (which is probably too large to store in your computer), it turns out that it can be off by either +1 or -1. Furthermore, an error of +1 does not necessarily imply that `n` is a power of `b`, which is assumed by trincot's answer. Accounting for these issues is relatively straightforward:

```py
def floor_log(n, b):
    res = math.floor(math.log(n, b))
    return res + 1 if b**(res+1) <= n else res - 1 if b**res > n else res
```

Or equivalently:

```py
def floor_log(n, b):
    res = math.floor(math.log(n, b))
    return res + (b**(res+1) <= n) - (b**res > n)
```

---

Testing edge cases near powers of `b`

```py
for p in [15, 30, 100, 1000]:
    for b in range(3, 50):
        for i in range(-2, 3):
            r, e = floor_log(b**p + i, b), p - (i < 0)
            assert r == e, f'floor_log({b}**{p} + {i}, {b}) = {r} but should be {e}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74099536/7741591), we can avoid the need to use a logarithm on `n`, only a logarithm on `b` is necessary, as well as provably reduce the number of cases that need to be checked for correction. It suffices to use the bit length as a good estimate first and then follow up with correction.

```py
from math import log

def floor_log(n, b):
    i = int(log(2, b) * (n.bit_length() - 1)) + 1
    return i - (b ** i > n)
```

The same logic is used as in the linked answer. Since the same base is probably used repeatedly, this can be further optimized using a cache:

```py
from functools import lru_cache, partial
from math import log

CACHE_SIZE = 10
log_of_2 = lru_cache(CACHE_SIZE)(partial(log, 2))

def floor_log(n, b):
    i = int(log_of_2(b) * (n.bit_length() - 1)) + 1
    return i - (b ** i > n)
```