# How to find the length of the integer variable

Tags: python

I have tried to find the length of the integer variable `var` with this method,

```
    var=1234567
    k=0
    while var>0:
        var//=10
        k+=1
    print("len of the integer is=",k)
```

Is there a alternative way to do this?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It's a duplicate of [How to find the length of the integer variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2189800/2745495).

Answer (score 1):

No need such complex logic. Try this.

```
print(len(str(var)))
```