# how can I grab a number from URL and check it's length in django?

Tags: django, url, django-models, phone-number

I need to verify the length of number grabbed from URL such as example.com/12345678 in django ?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", main.views.index, name="index"),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('<int:tnum>/', main.views.number, name="number")
```

And if the number doesn't match a certain length I want to output number is invalid.

Comment: please include your views too.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here:
[How to find length of digits in an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189800/how-to-find-length-of-digits-in-an-integer)

Essentially, you first convert the integer to a string and then get the length of the string.

So in your view, you will need to have some logic like this:

```
tnum_length = len(str(tnum))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding me, actually after I post the question I did find the same question you mentioned.