# divide a list of positive integers by the length of digits

Tags: python

I would like to divide a list of positive integers by the length of digits.
For example, int_list = `[1,3,13,888,1004]`
-> `[1,3] , [13] , [888] , [1004]`

I have implemented below:

```py
def seperate_by_digit(int_list):
    len_set = set()  # track how many digits we have

    int_dict = {}  # key : len of digits  / val : list of integer
    for int_ele in int_list:
        n = len(str(int_ele))
        if n not in len_set:
            int_dict[n] = [int_ele]
            len_set.add(n)
        else:
            sub_int_list = int_dict[n]
            sub_int_list.append(int_ele)
            int_dict[n] = sub_int_list
    return int_dict
```

Is there any better, cleaner way to complete this task?

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary 1 and 3 are grouped together because they have the same number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of the digits, it simpler to use the string representation.

Assuming you don't have negative numbers, one solution is to first sort your list, then [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) the list based on length.

```py
from itertools import groupby


def split_list(lst):
    return [list(g) for _, g in
            groupby(sorted(lst), key=lambda x: len(str(x)))]


lst = [1, 3, 13, 888, 1004]

print(split_list(lst))
```

output:

```
[[1, 3], [13], [888], [1004]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick implementation using a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd

def separate_by_digit(int_list):
    int_dict = dd(list)
    for k in int_list:
        int_dict[len(str(k))].append(k)
    return int_dict

print(list(separate_by_digit([1,3,13,888,1004]).values()))
```

Result:

```
[[1, 3], [13], [888], [1004]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this linke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189800/how-to-find-length-of-digits-in-an-integer) converting to `str` have performance issue, we can do it as:

```python
import math


def getIntegerPlaces(theNumber):
    if theNumber <= 999999999999997:
        return int(math.log10(theNumber)) + 1
    else:
        counter = 15
        while theNumber >= 10**counter:
            counter += 1
        return counter

def convert(l):
    m = {}
    for v in a:
        digitCount = getIntegerPlaces(v)
        if not digitCount in m:
            m[digitCount] = []
        m[digitCount].append(v)
    return list(m.values())

a = [1,3,13,888,1004]
print(convert(a))
```

The output will be:

```python
[[1, 3], [13], [888], [1004]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's multiple passes, but *a* way to accomplish this would be to create a `set` of the lengths of the numbers in `lst`.

```
lst = [1, 3, 13, 888, 1004]

lens = set(len(str(x)) for x in lst)
```

We can then iterate over this set and filter `lst` for each length.

```
grouped = [[x for x in lst if len(str(x)) == l] for l in lens]
```

End result:

```
[[1, 3], [13], [888], [1004]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a defaultdict to manage the grouping and length of the string value to get the number of digits:

```
from math import log
from collections import defaultdict

int_list = [1,3,13,888,1004]

int_dict = defaultdict(list)
for n in int_list:
    int_dict[len(str(n))].append(n)
    
print(*int_dict.values())
# [1, 3] [13] [888] [1004]
```

Comment: Yea, I guess using log isn't as straightforward as I thought.

Comment: You could use `log10`, that's apparently correct up to almost 10^15, which might suffice. But I think a really correct way like str is indeed better.