# Count number of digits using for loop in Python

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, numbers

I want to count number of digits of any digits number without converting the number to string and also using for loop. Can someone suggest how to do this.

```
num = int(input("Enter any number : "))
temp = num
count = 0
for i in str(temp):
    temp = temp // 10
    count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: The number of digits is simply `len(str(temp))`, you don't need to actually iterate `str(temp)` in order to count the number of digits in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find length of digits in an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189800/how-to-find-length-of-digits-in-an-integer) (There are 30+ answers on that question, some of which don't convert to string and also don't use loops. There doesn't need to be a separate question.)

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to using `input`, you can't get away the fact that this function prompts a `String`. As for the `for` loop, simply count the number of characters in the input string:

```
num = input("Enter any number : ")                                                                       
print(len(num))
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a `temp` variable as `num` already contains the input.

If there should only digits being entered, you can first check that with a pattern, then get the length of the string without using any loop.

```
import re

inp = input("Enter any number : ")
m = re.match(r"\d+$", inp)

if m:
    print(len(m.group()))
else:
    print("There we not only digits in the input.")
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps , though this only works for whole numbers int type i.e non-decimal point valued

```
import math as m
n:int=int(input())
print(int(m.log10(m))+1)
```

Comment: The code snippet is rather dense and there are no explanations provided.

It would be helpful if you could explain what you are doing with a little bit more text.