# how to find the amount of characters in unsigned long long

Tags: c, string-length, unsigned-long-long-int

hi I have 2 question the first one is the one in the title and the other one is here:
does unsigned long long is the biggest integer (can hold the biggest amount of characters)?
cause I need an int that can hold few millions characters (digits) is this possible? I'm coding in C.
and this is connecting me to the other question how can I display the amount of digits on the screen? is it need to be like this?:

```
printf("%d", intName.length)
```

thanks every one!!

Comment: `unsigned long long` having range only `0` to `2^64 - 1`. (`18,446,744,073,709,551,615`)

Comment: long long is not gonna cut it. You need a library like gmplib. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library

Comment: Why do you need numbers that have millions of digits?  Just wondering, since you "didn't understand nothing" of a pretty good answer, which makes me perplexed about what you might be trying to do.

Comment: If you need a number like 100 digits you could allocate 100 bytes of memory and there to store 1 digit as 1 byte. You would need to implement your own add/sub/div/mul... function calculations. We were doing something like this in uni in Pascal, where we had to make sum of 2 mega-long floating point numbers. Was interesting for practicing and finding best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that when you refer to the amount of characters you mean the number of digits in the number. If so then one [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068849/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-digits-of-an-integer-in-c) has everything you need to know and included code similar to this

```
int numberOfDigits(unsigned long long n) 
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    return floor( log10( abs( n ) ) ) + 1;
}
```

as for holding a few million digits you probably want to look into using a library such as [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/) which includes the function

```
size_t mpz_sizeinbase( const mpz_t op, int base )
```

which will tell you how many digits your number has.

Comment: yes that what I mean but can you explain to me what is the meaning of this piece of code, because if I just copy past it to my program I didn't understand nothing!!!

Comment: from the inside out we have

Comment: [sorry hit enter by mistake and got cutoff above] from the inside out we have `abs(n)` this is making sure the log10 function gets a positive number, `log10(...)` tells us how many powers of 10 fit into our number... so if n was 100 then `log10(100)` would be 2, or if n was 10000 then `log10(10000)` would be 4. Next is `floor(...)` which is just there to make sure that the result is an integer since the result of log10 was probably not a whole number. Lastly we add the `+ 1` to account for the last digit in the number such as the 3 in 13 since it isn't included in our count of powers of ten.

Comment: didn't compile, didn't give you the correct result, ???? Have you included math.h ?

Comment: and yes I did include math.h

Comment: yeh, thats not giving me enough to go on... first guess is theres a problem happening in the conversion from unsigned long long to the double used in the math.h functions... afraid your gonna have to hit the text books sorry

Comment: @NSH you may forgot to put `-lm` option to include math library compiled binary

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%llu", xxxxxxxxx);

 the ll (el-el) long-long modifier with the u (unsigned) conversion
```

you can also use

```
 uint64_t a;
 uint32_t b;
```

But you need to inlcude inttypes.h library that gives you types such as int32_t, int64_t, uint64_t.

Comment: can you please explain more because I'm kind of new to C

Answer (score 0):

C99 provides intmax_t (and uintmax_t) which will be the largest supported integer type (typically 64 bit.)

Assuming you have a conforming C99 snprintf then you can get the number of digits with:

```
length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", value);
```

for an unsigned long long value (and %ju for uintmax_t.)

Otherwise you'll have to pass a buffer in (yuk) or do something manually like:

```
length = value < 10 ? 1 :
         value < 100 ? 2 :
         ...
```

also yuk!

But this is all pretty irrelevant if you really do want million-digit integers, in which case you'll need to use a library such as gmp to work with such big numbers.

Comment: I'm new to C so can someone explain it in basic C language?

Comment: I suggest you get more comfortable with some basic C exercises then have a go solving your problem using the GMP library.

Comment: I already know the basics and the million digits number isn't the issue what I need is the "how-many-digits" show on the screen with a simple printf(); commend. can it be?

Answer (score 0):

The maximal decimal length of an unsigned integer of a given type of bit length `bitlen` is given by `1 + floor(log10(2^bitlen-1))` (mathematically, without taking overflows and rounding errors into account). The approximation `1/log2(10) ~ 4004.0/13301` (obtained with continued fractions, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) leads to the formula `1 + bitlen * 4004 / 13301` (computationally, i.e. the division rounds down). Mathematical details are given in the comments of the snippet below.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * Maximal number of digits in the decimal representation of an unsigned type.
 *
 * floor( log2(2^bitlen - 1) / log2(10) ) == floor( bitlen / log2(10) )
 * otherwise an integer n would exist with
 *     log2(2^bitlen - 1) / log2(10) < n < bitlen / log2(10)
 *     log2(2^bitlen - 1) < n * log2(10) < bitlen
 *     2^bitlen - 1 < 2^(n * log2(10)) < 2^bitlen
 *     2^bitlen - 1 < (2^log2(10))^n < 2^bitlen
 *     2^bitlen - 1 < 10^n < 2^bitlen
 *     which is impossible
 *
 * 1 / log2(10) ~ 0.301029995663981
 * 4004 / 13301 ~ 0.30102999774453
 *
 *     1 + floor( log10(2^bitlen - 1) )
 *  == 1 + floor( log2(2^bitlen - 1) / log2(10) )
 *  == 1 + floor( bitlen / log2(10) )
 *  <= 1 + floor( bitlen * 4004.0 / 13301 )
 *  == 1 + bitlen * 4004 / 13301
 * with equality for bitlen <= 13300 == 8 * 1662.5
 */
#define DECLEN(unsigned_t) (1 + CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned_t) * 4004 / 13301)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("unsigned char      : %zu\n", DECLEN(unsigned char));
    printf("short unsigned     : %zu\n", DECLEN(short unsigned));
    printf("unsigned           : %zu\n", DECLEN(unsigned));
    printf("long unsigned      : %zu\n", DECLEN(long unsigned));
    printf("long long unsigned : %zu\n", DECLEN(long long unsigned));
    return 0;
}
```