# Count digits of number without loop C++

Tags: c++

I have to count the number of digits in a number.

I  divide the number to 10 until I get 0. Each iteration increments the counter.

```
int num;
cin>>num;  
while(num > 0)  
{  
  counter++;
  num = num / 10;   
}
```

The challenge is not using any loops or recursion, just an `if` statement.

Is it possible?

Comment: How about a recursive function?

Comment: @dolan, Nice idea! Like! but it is also forbidden in this case :-(

Comment: @yaelaviv `log10(n)+1` where `n` is the number. For example, `log10(1234) + 1` is 4.

Comment: If you can't use recursion you should state that in the question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, why  `+1`?

Comment: @yaelaviv Because of math :D `log10` of thousands is 3.something, `int` value is 3, hence you need the +1. `log10` of hundreds is 2 and so on..

Comment: Actually, I _thought_ I'd seen something similar before: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068849/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-digits-of-an-integer-in-c/1068937#1068937

Answer (score 13, accepted):

counter = log(num) / log(10)

in c++:

```
#include <cmath>
....
counter = num == 0 ? 1 : log10(std::abs(num)) + 1;
```

what you want is the log function.

cplusplus - [log10](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log10/)

cplusplus - [std::abs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/)

Comment: Still broken for `num == 0` though.

Comment: @Vladp, Does log10 have to use double variables?

Comment: This doesn't work for num == int min (on a 2s complement machine). I'm not sure what standard says std::abs does in that case but the answer it gives is clearly wrong. [see http://ideone.com/exvOQK]

Comment: @Mike, `std::abs()` inherits from the C `stdlib` header, which specifies undefined behaviour if the result cannot be represented.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way although somewhat expensive, turn your number to string and take its size like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  int i = 1232323223;
  std::string str = std::to_string(std::abs(i));
  std::cout << "Number of Digits: " << str.size() <<std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e218cb97c4e554a)

Comment: Doesn't work for int min (on a 2s complement machine)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `sprintf`, since it returns the number of characters emitted:

```
int digits(int n)
{
    char s[32];
    int len = sprintf(s, "%d", n);
    if (n < 0) len--; // NB: handle negative case
    return len;
}
```

Comment: I think `s` should be `temp` (or vice versa), yes?

Answer (score 3):

Sure it's possible, something like (for 32-bit numbers):

```
int numDigitsU (unsigned int n) {
    if (n <         10) return 1;
    if (n <        100) return 2;
    if (n <       1000) return 3;
    if (n <      10000) return 4;
    if (n <     100000) return 5;
    if (n <    1000000) return 6;
    if (n <   10000000) return 7;
    if (n <  100000000) return 8;
    if (n < 1000000000) return 9;
    /*      4294967295 is 2^32-1 - add more ifs as needed
       and adjust this final return as well. */
    return 10;
}
```

The signed variant is a little trickier since the sign is reversed first, and you have to watch out for `MININT`:

```
int numDigitsS (int n) {
    if (n == MININT) n = MAXINT;  // same number of digits, usually.
    if (n < 0) n = -n;            // reverse sign.
    return numDigitsU (n);        // call the unsigned variant.
}
```

Just adjust the highest comparison value and return value based on the size of your largest `unsigned int`.

This should work with all allowed negative codings: two's complement, ones' complement, and sign/magnitude.

Comment: dang, you were 10 seconds faster :), +1.

Comment: Here you are actually unrolling the loop. OK is faster than using a for loop but quite verbose also.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually quite easy if you consider that the maximum size of `int` is finite. Just check if the number is larger than 10, larger than 100, larger than 1000, etc. You could even do binary search.

```
int num = abs(number);
if (num < 10000)
{
    if (num < 100)
        return num < 10 ? 1:2;
    else
        return num < 1000 ? 3:4;   
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `you could even do binary search` how?

Comment: @yael Edit: Provided an example

Answer (score 0):

You can find the length of an integer just by doing it as follows:

```
int countDigits(int *num){
    int count =0;
    while(*num>0){
        count++;
        *num /=10;
    }
    return count;
}
```