# How do I expand the order when displaying characters?

Tags: c++

I need to change the order of the symbol display but without **recursion** and a second **cycle**.

the `sow` code is displayed but I need to get the `wos`

```
int test = 119111115; // wos

for (; test > 0; test /= 1000) {
        std::cout << (char)(test % 1000);
}
    
// > sow
```

do not use a **string** or anything related to it.

Comment: The end length of your c-string would be `ceil(log10(test))/3 + 1`, so that can be known ahead of time. From there, you could simply have a "divisor" you multiply by 1000 each loop iteration, as well as an index you decrement each loop, the inserting the characters into the array in reverse. (To clarify, `log10` of a number would give you 1 for 10, 2 for 100, 3 for 1000,  3.xxx for 1001-9999, etc. You can use this to get the number of digits in a number, keep in mind the edge cases listed above! I didn't handle it). After all that, you'll have your finished c-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking out thousands groupings from an `int` to display the ASCII value of is a rather strange task. You have `"sow"` handled fine. You need to basically do the same thing in reverse for `"wos"`. While there a many, many ways to handle the arithmetic, following on your form of and limiting the algorithm to *one-loop* and using a lookup-table for the divisor, you could do something similar to:

```
    int test = 119111115,
        thous[] = { 1, 1000, 1000000, 1000000000 };
    
    for (int i = sizeof test - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int div = thous[i],
            result = test / div;
        if (result)
            std::cout << (char)result;
        test -= result * div;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
```

Which just uses `div` as the divisor and loops `3`, `2`, `1`, and `0` as the exponent to divide `test` by. It tests the `result` and if it is non-zero then outputs the ASCII value of that grouping and then eliminates that value from `test`.

Both `"sow"` and `"wos"` put together could be written:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    
    int test = 119111115,
        thous[] = { 1, 1000, 1000000, 1000000000 };
    
    /* sow */
    for (; test > 0; test /= 1000)
        std::cout << (char)(test % 1000);
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    test = 119111115; // wos
    
    /* wos */
    for (int i = sizeof test - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int div = thous[i],
            result = test / div;
        if (result)
            std::cout << (char)result;
        test -= result * div;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sow
sow
wos
```

This is just one way to do it. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: ARRGH -- you are right! (you could cheat and use a function. I'll play with it a bit more.

Comment: I like your version, trying to understand how it works, it seems you have an extra iteration of the cycle due to the number `1000000000` perhaps this is unnecessary

Comment: `for (int i = sizeof test - 2; i >= 0; i--) {`

Comment: Yes, to make it general, we iterate over all 4 potential groups. When there are no values that would translate into characters for that group the division `div` will be greater than `test` making `result == 0` and that grouping is simply skipped.

Comment: @DonAllocine This will still fail if `int` is 16-bit or 64-bit for example. And if you assume that an `int` is always 32-bit then you don't need a loop at all, just a couple of `if` will suffice.

Comment: @dxiv - no, it will work for 16-bit or 64-bit, the issue is the thousand groupings must hold an ASCII value. That's why I opened with doing it that way is kind of weird. Take `int test = 65122` for example, A 16-bit value. (`"Az"` and `"zA"`) That's why this is more a coding exercise rather than the implementation of some bit of code that will be generally useful outside the exercise.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If `int` is 64-bit the maximum `test` value is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. The code can be fixed by making `thous` twice as large, but you still have to hardcode a maximum size.

Comment: Yes, of course, there will be hardcoding of a max size. Whenever you do wonky things, you are not going to be able to write purist code to accomplish it. I'm not disagreeing with you are all.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int test = 119111115; // wos

    for (; test > 0;) {
        string temp = std::to_string(test);

        // Get first three characters and convert it to ASCII char
        std::cout << (char) stoi(temp.substr(0, 3));

        if (temp.size() > 3 )
            // Remove first three characters
            test = stoi(temp.erase(0,3));
        else
            test = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
wos
```

If you want to get rid of `to_string`, you can

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


unsigned int number_of_int( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned int number_of_digits = 0;

    do {
         ++number_of_digits; 
         n /= 10;
    } while (n);

    return number_of_digits;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int test = 119111115; // wos

    for (; test > 0;) {
        // int length = to_string(test).length();
        // int length = number_of_int(test);
        int length =  test == 0 ? 1 : log10(std::abs(test)) + 1;
        int first3 = test / pow(10, length-3);

        std::cout << (char) first3;
        if (length > 3)
            // Remove first three characters
            test = test % (unsigned long)pow(10, length-3);
        else
            test = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please do not use `to_string`

Comment: @DonAllocine Thanks for your follow up. If you don't want to use `to_string` but still want to get first three number of an int value. I think you can get the int length first. Then divide it with 10^(length-3). I will edit my answer soon.

Comment: the main thing that would not need to create a second loop or recursion, and then it will be super

Comment: not suitable you are using another cycle `do while`

Comment: @DonAllocine See my updated answer. It uses https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721235/10315163 to get rid of original loop function which is used to calculate number of digit.

Comment: unfortunately I don't understand your version yet