# Finding a number at a particular digit in a number

Tags: c++, c++11, numbers, integer, digits

I want to get number present at the specific index.

Suppose the number is "123456789" and i need to return the number at position 3 from left.

Should I convert this number to a string and re-convert the char at specific index to integer to get the number value?

Is there any inbuilt function to do so in C++?

Comment: Is the number integer, or a string? The question is vague.

Comment: integer @VioletGiraffe

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because student did not show any effort to solve his homework.

Comment: Easiest way is probably to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the third digit that of a number!

```
cout << "Enter an integer";
int number;
cin >> number;
int n = number / 100 % 10
```

Or (for all digits):

```
 int number = 12345;
 int numSize = 5;
for (int i=numSize-1; i>=0; i--) {
  int y = pow(10, i);
  int z = number/y;
  int x2 = number / (y * 10);
  printf("%d-",z - x2*10 );
}
```

Comment: But the OP specified he wanted the third digit from the *left*, not from the *right*.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe 12345/1000=12

Comment: The general idea of this answer may still work in conjunction with [counting the digits](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1068849) (to compute `numSize`).

Answer (score 5):

To get the digit at any place in the number than you can use a simple string conversion:

```
int foo = 123456789;
int pos = 3;
// convert to string and use the [] operator
std::cout << std::to_string(foo)[pos - 1];//need to subtract 1 as C++ is 0 index based
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of std::stringstream

```
std::string showMSD3(int foo)
{
   std::stringstream ssOut;

   std::string sign;
   std::stringstream ss1;
   if(foo < 0) {
      ss1 << (-1 * foo);
      sign = '-';
   }
   else
      ss1 << foo;

   std::string s = ss1.str();

   ssOut << "               foo string: '"
         << sign << s << "'" << std::endl;

   if(s.size() > 2)
   {
      ssOut << " Most Significant Digit 3: "
            << s[2] // 1st digit at offsset 0
            << "\n            has hex value: 0x"
            << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex
            << (s[2] - '0')
            << std::endl;
   }
   else
      ssOut << "                      Err: foo has only "
            << s.size() << " digits" << std::endl;

   return (ssOut.str());
}
```

and somewhere closer to main (perhaps in main):

```
   // test 1
   {
      std::cout << showMSD3(123456789) << std::endl;
   }

   // test 2
   {
      std::cout << showMSD3(12) << std::endl;
   }

   // test 3 - handle negative integer
   {
      std::cout << showMSD3(-123) << std::endl;
   }
```

with output

```
               foo string: '123456789'
 Most Significant Digit 3: 3
            has hex value: 0x03

               foo string: '12'
                      Err: foo has only 2 digits

               foo string: '-123'
 Most Significant Digit 3: 3
            has hex value: 0x03
```