# How can I picking numbers of numbers in python?

Tags: python, time-series, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, finance

I need the pick first 3 numbers if input numbers.
Example;

```
23456.43 = 234

7348593.8304853 = 734

1.097493 = 109

27.7481 = 277
```

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: `str(your_input).replace('.','')[:3]`?

Comment: do you know if the input is a float or can it be letters there too?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Please repeat your materials on string handling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get most significant digit in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947632/get-most-significant-digit-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
number  = 23.4563
x  = int(str(number).replace('.', '') [:3])
print(x)
```

output :

```
234
```