# Getting number of int digits

Tags: c, function, digits

I'm reading an integer from a file using `fscanf(fp, "%d", &n)` function.

Is there a way to know how many digits that number has without loops?

Comment: There is no reason why you would want to do that without loops. All present answers are inferior to the simple `unsigned int digits = 1; while(n > base) { n /= base; digits++;  }`. Using strings, float numbers and other such nonsense is just bad programming. You've started a competition over who can write the worst program, so I think this question is harmful to future readers.

Comment: `unsigned int digits = 1; not_a_loop: if(n > base) { n /= base; digits++; goto not_a_loop; }`  There you go. 100 times more effective than any of the answers posted.

Comment: @Lundin, certainly you meant `while(n >= base)`. (>= vs >). As for me I would have used: `unsigned int digits = 0; do { digits++; n /= base; } while(n);  }`.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1068849/2410359 (possible dupe)

Comment: @Lundin - you may like [`int n = 1; while (n /= 10) n++;`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069045/2410359)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
int count = 0;
fscanf(fp, "%d%n", &n, &count);
```

The `%n` specifier puts in `count` the number of characters read so far.

However, this number can be larger that the number of digits of `n` because the `%d` specifier allows skipping whitespace characters before it reads the number.

Check @pmg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35480385/4265352) to see how to count those whitespaces.

Comment: See my answer. We had the same idea, but I counted the whitespace and subtracted from the result.

Answer (score 3):

```
int optionalwhitespace, characters;
if (fscanf(fp, " %n%d%n", &optionalwhitespace, &n, &characters) != 1) /* error */;
characters -= optionalwhitespace;
// characters now has the number of characters read to interpret the value in n
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, by reading it as a string:

```
char buffer[256];
fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer);
int length = strlen(buffer);
```

NOTE: if it is a negative number, you might want to discount the `-` sign...

Suppose you still want to have the integer value:

```
int n = atoi(buffer);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that `strlen()` give 256?

Comment: @matt95 `strlen` will stop counting at `\0` character.

Comment: Please note that this is _far_ slower than reading it as an int and using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `log` function:

```
int number_of_digits(unsigned int i)
{
    return (int)(log(i+1) / log(10)) + 1;
}

int main (void)
{
    int i = 52;
    printf("%d has %d digits\n", number_of_digits(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For code golf approach, just return the value of `snprintf()`

```
width = snprintf(0, 0, "%u", (unsigned) n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snprinf`, which is a better option than `itoa`:

```
int x = 0;
scanf( "%d", &x );
char buffer[20] = "";
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", x);
printf( "num of digits = %d", strlen(buffer) );
```

Comment: Why 20?  Could use 1 or `printf( "num of digits = %d", snprintf(0, 0, "%d", x) );`

Comment: @chux - the syntax looks very strange to me, but indeed it works. `snprintf` manpage never mentions the first param can be NULL - so I suppose that exploit must come from inspecting the code of `snprintf` itself??

Comment: Rather than derived references like a manapge, consider using the C spec.  Draft versions readily google-able on-line.  "`snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n, const char * restrict format, ...);` ... If n is zero, nothing is written, and s may be a null pointer. ... The snprintf function returns the number of characters that would have been written had n been sufficiently large ..."  No need for exploit or  inspecting the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <math.h>
number > 0 ? (int) log10 ((double) number) + 1 : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just count `log10` of that number and round it up like so:

```
int length = ceil(log10((double)n)) + 0.5;
```

`+ 0.5` Is for casting floating point number to integer, because number like 3 cant be written explicitly in floating point representation doing `(int)3.0` may yield 2. I am assuming that `ceil` doesn't return answer off by `0.5` which is never going to happen.

Comment: Casting `(double)` can lose precision in `n`.

Comment: @chux I assumed it was `int` not 64 bit integer.

Comment: Adding the 0.5 serves not purpose here. `ceil()` returns a whole number value,  why add 0.5 to it only to truncate when converted to `int`

Comment: @chux `ceil` doesn't return integer value. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/

Comment: The  C spec says "The `ceil` functions compute the smallest integer value not less than `x`."  Are they wrong too?

Comment: You haven't read the link, it says "Rounds x upward, returning the smallest integral value that is not less than x" but in `double`. Send me reference to that C spec then.

Comment: Ref: `C11 7.12.9.1 The ceil functions`.  Easy enough to google and find an on-line version.  I prefer the C spec to a c++ site.

Comment: IAC, so the `ceil()` returns a whole/integer/integral value. Why add 0.5 to that result?  I have seen code where folks have used the inferior `ceil(x + 0.5)` vs instead of `round(x)`.  This is the first that suggests adding 0.5 _after_ computing `ceil()` and then convert to `int`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to know how many digits that number has without loops?

A recursion solution

```
unsigned digit_count(unsigned x) {
  if (x >= 10) return digit_count(x /10) + 1;
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<math.h>

//rest of program
fscanf(fp, "%d", &n)
int length = (int)(log10(n)) +1;
//rest of program
```

Comment: Errr...  `log10(*n)`?  I don't think you meant to dereference that integer as a pointer.

Comment: Oops! Edited. Thanks.