# Increment function with pointers not working

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to find the number of digits in a given number through the use of pointers.

This code below will give the correct output,

```
void numDigits(int num, int *result) {
  *result = 0;

  do {
    *result += 1;
    num = num / 10;
  } while (num > 0);
}
```

However, if I change the `*result += 1;` line to `*result++;`, the output will no longer be correct and only give 0.

What is going on here?

Comment: Check this will helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068849/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-digits-of-an-integer-in-c

Comment: Do you mean `(*result)++`or `*(result++)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C/C++, precedence of Prefix `++` (or Prefix `--`) has higher priority than dereference (`*`) operator, and precedence of Postfix `++` (or Postfix `--`) is higher than both Prefix `++` and `*`.

If `p` is a pointer then `*p++` is equivalent to `*(p++)` and `++*p` is equivalent to `++(*p)` (both Prefix `++` and `*` are right associative).

Answer (score 1):

`*result++` is interpreted as `*(result++)`.

Answer (score 0):

the order of evaluation is the increment is first, then you dereference the pointer, the value of the pointer stays the same for the line in the expression if it's a postfix.
what you are trying to do is to increment the dereference of the pointer so you need to put the parenthesis on the dereference then increment it, like this: `(*result)++;`