# How to allocate enough memory to convert an unsigned long long int into string

Tags: c, printf, malloc, 64-bit

With a code where I have a struct:

```
struct fibo_entry {                 /* Definition of each table entry */
    int n;
    unsigned long long int lli;     /* 64-bit integer */
    char *str;
};
```

I have to solve a Fibonacci sequence where I have the following:

```
    fibo_table = (struct fibo_entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct fibo_entry));
    //fibo_table->str = (char *)malloc(1 + 8 * sizeof(char)); // !!??

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        fibo_table[i].n = i;

    if (i == 0) {
        fibo_table[i].lli = 0;
        //sprintf(fibo_table[i].str, "%llu", fibo_table[i].lli);
        //fibo_table[i].str = atoi(fibo_table[i].lli);
      
    } else if (i == 1) {
        fibo_table[i].lli = 1;
    } else {
        fibo_table[i].lli = fibo_table[i-1].lli + fibo_table[i-2].lli;
        //log10(fibo_table[i].lli);
    }
}
```

The process to calculate Fibonacci is done, the problem that I have comes when I have to calculate the memory that I need to allocate a long long int in the string.

I know that the numbers use 64 bits each and I tried with malloc and the concept that `sprintf` should work to convert one in another, but I can't find a solution. Every time that I try to run the program, just fail.

Comment: do you really need to save it to a string, or do you just need to `printf` it?

Comment: Why do you need to the number as a string anyway? This is totally redundant. Otherwise you could use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/). Read its documentation closely, especially the "Return value" section.

Comment: 2^64 = 18446744073709551616-1, so the longest string can be `strlen("18446744073709551615")+1`

Comment: Related question: [How do I determine the number of digits of an integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1068849/10077)

Comment: more pertinent, you're allocating space for only one `struct fibo_entry` .. so you're invoking undefined behavior for every `n > 0` in your `for` loop. If `n == 0` always then no need for the loop.

Comment: `sizeneeded = 1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", longlongunsignedvalue);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a (positive) number, *n*, in *decimal* notation (as the `%llu` format specifier will), then the number of digits will be (the integral part of) log<sub>10</sub>(*n*) + 1.

So, in order to (pre-)determine the maximum buffer size required, you can use the `log10` function on the compiler-defined constant, `ULLONG_MAX` (this is the maximum value that an `unsigned long long int` can have). Note that, when allocating the character buffer, you should add 1 to the number of digits, to allow for the `nul`-terminator in your string.

The following short program may be helpful:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    size_t maxdigits = (size_t)(log10((double)(ULLONG_MAX)) + 1);
    printf("Max. digits in unsigned long long = %zu!\n", maxdigits);
    printf("Max. value for the type is: %llu\n", ULLONG_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

On *most* modern systems, `unsigned long long int` will be 64 bits, with a maximum value of `18446744073709551615` (20 digits); however, it is better to use the platform/compiler-specific `ULLONG_MAX`, rather than relying on any particular value being correct.

Further, rather than calculating this `maxdigits` value multiple times, you need only calculate a 'global' constant *once*, then re-use that as and when required.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: `static const size_t maxdigits = sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT * 30103 / 100000 + 1;` provides a compile-time constant and does not require a math routine. (.30103 is a smidge over log(2).)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fantastic - but shouldn't that be taking `sizeof(unsigned long long)`?

Comment: @BrunoMartín As yano pointed out in the comments, you need to allocate space for `n+1` structures, not just one: `fibo_table = malloc(sizeof(struct fibo_entry) * (n+1));`

Answer (score 0):

> How to allocate enough memory to convert an unsigned long long int into string

With an `n`-bit unsigned integer, a buffer of `log10(2^n - 1) + 1 + 1` is needed.  +1 for "ceiling" and +1 for the null character.

To find this value at compiler time, could use:

```
#define LOG10_2_N 302
#define LOG10_2_D 1000
#define ULL_STR_SIZE1 (sizeof (unsigned long long)*CHAR_BIT * LOG10_2_N / LOG10_2_D + 2)
```

To find this at pre-processor time is a little trickier as we need to find the bit width via macros.  This approach also takes space advantage if rare padding bits are used.

```
// Numbers of bits in a Mersenne Number
// https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m)/((m)%255+1) / 255%255*8 + 7-86/((m)%255+12))
#define ULLONG_BIT_WIDTH IMAX_BITS(ULLONG_MAX)

// 28/93 is a tight fraction for log10(2)
#define LOG10_2_N 28
#define LOG10_2_D 93
#define ULL_STR_SIZE2 (ULLONG_BIT_WIDTH * LOG10_2_N / LOG10_2_D + 1 + 1)
```

`ULL_STR_SIZE2` is suitable for `#if ULL_STR_SIZE2 ...` processing.

```
fibo_table[i].str = malloc(ULL_STR_SIZE2);
if (fibo_table[i].str) {
  sprintf(fibo_table[i].str, "%llu", fibo_table[i].lli);
```

Or at run-time, to "right size", call `snprintf()` first and find the size needed for per each integer via the return value of `*printf()`.

```
int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", fibo_table[i].lli);
fibo_table[i].str = malloc(n + 1);
if (fibo_table[i].str) {
  sprintf(fibo_table[i].str, "%llu", fibo_table[i].lli);
```

Or slightly more efficient, form a worst case size temporary buffer, write to it and then duplicate the string.

```
char tmp[ULL_STR_SIZE2];
snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%llu", fibo_table[i].lli);
fibo_table[i].str = strdup(tmp);
```

---

Alternative: change pointer `char *str` to an array.

```
struct fibo_entry {
  int n;
  unsigned long long int lli;
  //char *str;
  char *str[ULL_STR_SIZE2];
};
```

and use

```
snprintf(fibo_table[i].str, sizeof fibo_table[i].str, "%llu", fibo_table[i].lli);
```

---

Best to not assume `long long` is 64-bit.  It is *at least* 64-bit.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, answer amended.

Comment: FYI, 146/485 is a much tighter fraction for log10(2)

Comment: @SGeorgiades Yes 146/485 is optimal to bitwidths 28000+.  28/93 is sufficient for bit widths up to 92.  Either fraction, when not optimal does error on being a tad too big.  With pre-processor math being at least 63-bit, many such fractions are possible including 301031/1000000 being clearly derived from log10(2) = 0.301030927835...

Comment: Should be 0.3010299956...  --> 301030/1000000 or `30103L/100000`

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t CountDigit(long long int num)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    if(num < 0)
    {
        count++;
    }

    while (num)
    {
         count++;
         num \=10;
    }
    count++;\\thats for the '\0'
    return (count);
}
```

then you can use count for malloc and after that you can use sprintf or do it yourself, to insert the right chars in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate how many digits you need to use doing something like `number_digits = (int)log10((double)num) + 1;` and then reserve enough space with `fibo_table[i].str = malloc(number_digits * sizeof(char));` remember you need to do this every for iteration, after those two steps you can now use the sprintf as you were `sprintf(fibo_table[i].str, "%llu", fibo_table[i].lli);`, code would look something like this:

```c
 int number_digits;
 for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
 if (i == 0) {
  ....
 } else if (i == 1) {
  ....
 } else {
  ....
 }
 number_digits = (int)log10((double)i) + 1;
 fibo_table[i].str = malloc(number_digits*sizeof(char));
 sprintf(fibo_table[i].str, "%llu", fibo_table[i].lli);
}
```